# Converting List<String> to String[] in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion

How do I convert a [list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of String into an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)? The following code returns an error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    strlist.add("sdfs1");
    strlist.add("sdfs2");
    String[] strarray = (String[]) strlist.toArray();       
    System.out.println(strarray);
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
    at test.main(test.java:10)
```

Comment: For most questions with an error, you should post up the error message that you are receiving.

Comment: I like stackoverflow more.  Thanks for ranking 1 in google.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You want

```
String[] strarray = strlist.toArray(new String[0]);
```

See [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])) for the documentation and note that you can also call this method in such a way that it populates the passed array, rather than just using it to work out what type to return.  Also note that maybe when you print your array you'd prefer

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strarray));
```

since that will print the actual elements.

Comment: Using strlist.toArray(new String[strlist.size()]);  is usually more efficient.

Answer (score 20):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    strlist.add("sdfs1");
    strlist.add("sdfs2");

    String[] strarray = new String[strlist.size()]
    strlist.toArray(strarray );

    System.out.println(strarray);


}
```

Comment: I also favour this version of the `toArray` method because it re-uses the parameter strarray, instead of returning a new instance

Answer (score 3):

`List.toArray()` necessarily returns an array of Object. To get an array of String, you need to use the casting syntax:

```
String[] strarray = strlist.toArray(new String[0]);
```

See the javadoc for java.util.List for more.

Answer (score 2):

I've designed and implemented [Dollar](http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar/) for this kind of tasks:

```
String[] strarray= $(strlist).toArray();
```

Comment: Your $ API looks great, maybe couple methods like 'sort' could accept comparators that would make it even more useful.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to send me patches or open feature requests using bitbucket.

Comment: In order to see your implementation , I have to install 20M program to 'clone' your 254.3 KB source.

Comment: use the "get source" button on the right: here a link of the latest revision http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar/get/tip.zip

Answer (score 1):

hope this can help someone out there:

List list = ..;

String [] stringArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

great answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4042464/1547266

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] strarray = strlist.toArray(new String[0]);
```

If you want `List<String>` to convert to string use `StringUtils.join(slist, '\n');`