# Convert ArrayList<String> to String[] array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm working in the android environment and have tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
String [] stockArr = (String[]) stock_list.toArray();
```

If I define as follows:

```
String [] stockArr = {"hello", "world"};
```

it works. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: use `String [] stockArr = (String[]) stock_list.toArray(new String[0]);` refer [java doc here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28java.lang.Object[]%29)

Comment: @Nishant You do not need to cast! `String[] stockArr = stock_list.toArray(new String[0]);` is enough.

Comment: Have [made this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51545546/1746118) with an updated approach with **JDK-11** introducing a new an equally performant API to `toArray(T[])` and similar in syntax to `Stream.toArray`.

Answer (score 1834, accepted):

Use like this.

```
List<String> stockList = new ArrayList<String>();
stockList.add("stock1");
stockList.add("stock2");

String[] stockArr = new String[stockList.size()];
stockArr = stockList.toArray(stockArr);

for(String s : stockArr)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: To provide an explanation as to what is going on here, the JVM doesn't know how to blindly downcast Object[] (the result of toArray()) to String[]. To let it know what your desired object type is, you can pass a typed array into toArray(). The typed array can be of any size (new String[1] is valid), but if it is too small then the JVM will resize it on it's own.

Comment: @dhackner - *"...  the JVM doesn't know how to blindly downcast Object[] to String[]"*.  Or more precisely, **it is not allowed** to do that.  If it could do that, it would violate Java type safety.

Comment: Use `stock_list.toArray(stockArr)` instead of `stockArr = stock_list.toArray(stockArr)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9572820/597657

Comment: It may be useful to noobies too that, should your array list contain `double, floats, ints, longs` (primitive types), you must define your array/arraylist as containing a primitive type object, e.g. `Double, Float, Integer, Long`. And then from there your normal arrays must be defined with this type, e.g. `Double[] myDoubleArray = list.toArray(new Double[listOfDoubles.size()]);`

Comment: @dhackner How would it use the given array? As far as I know, arrays can't be resized...

Comment: @vishal No, it does not. If you forget to pass `.toArray()` a *typed array* then you get an `Object[]` array and "incompatible types" warning trying to assign the result to `stockArr`. This code runs as-is. It's `.toArray(stockArr);`

Comment: I solved using casting. On my return statement I used `return (String[]) myArrayList.toArray();`

Comment: Why do you have to write `stockArr` twice in `stockArr = stockList.toArray(stockArr);` ?

Comment: Don't use `stockList.size()` as the size, but 0, because of JVM optimizations when the size is 0, it doesn't have to overwrite the memory of the array with empty values, before returning it, leading to speedup.https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/

Comment: According to Joshua Bloch in Effective Java, preallocating the array harms performance. Provide a zero-length array instead. `stockList.toArray(new String[0])`

Comment: doesn't work for primitive types (long[], only for classes Long[])

Answer (score 979):

Try this

```
String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Comment: Object[] obj = stock_list.toArray();
String[] stockArr =new String[obj.length];
for(int i=0;i<stockArr.length;i++)
{
 stockArr[i]= (String) obj[i];
}

Comment: For anyone wondering what's going on in @QuanNguyen's comment: He is basically retrieving the `Object[]` by `.toArray()` and then manually copying the contents over to a new `String[]`, casting each element to a `String`. *It's a bad approach and you should instead just pass the new `String[]` to `.toArray()`*

Comment: You don't need to pass `list.size()`, this will just create an overhead of a bigger temporary array created that will be discarded right away. I could just be `String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[] {});`. Still giving +1 due to simplicity of oneliner answer.

Comment: @LeoHolanda, If the array provided in the parameter fits the list, the same array is used, if the size doesn't fit, it allocates an array itself, in your case, you end up creating a dummy array (of size 0).

Comment: Beware that `toArray(new String[0])` is [actually faster](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/) than `toArray(new String[list.size()])`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/converting-arrayliststring-to-string-in-java

Comment: I reverted the edit to keep the comments relevant. The other answers already report the `new String[0]` version

Answer (score 326):

What is happening is that `stock_list.toArray()` is creating an `Object[]` rather than a `String[]` and hence the typecast is failing<sup>1</sup>.

The correct code would be:

```
  String [] stockArr = stockList.toArray(new String[stockList.size()]);
```

or even

```
  String [] stockArr = stockList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

For more details, refer to the javadocs for the two overloads of `List.toArray`.

The latter version uses the zero-length array to determine the type of the result array.  (Surprisingly, it is faster to do this than to preallocate ... at least, for recent Java releases.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4042464/139985 for details.)

From a technical perspective, the reason for this API behavior / design is that an implementation of the `List<T>.toArray()` method has no information of what the `<T>` is at runtime.  All it knows is that the raw element type is `Object`.  By contrast, in the other case, the array parameter gives the base type of the array.  (If the supplied array is big enough to hold the list elements, it is used.  Otherwise a new array of the same type and a larger size is allocated and returned as the result.)

---

<sup>1 - In Java, an `Object[]` is not assignment compatible with a `String[]`.  If it was, then you could do this:</sup>

```
    Object[] objects = new Object[]{new Cat("fluffy")};
    Dog[] dogs = (Dog[]) objects;
    Dog d = dogs[0];     // Huh???
```

<sup>This is clearly nonsense, and that is why array types are not generally assignment compatible.</sup>

Comment: This doesn't work with primitive types.

Comment: If you mean, it worn convert a `List<Integer>` to an `int[]` ... that is correct.  It converts it to an `Integer[]`.

Answer (score 169):

An alternative in Java 8:

```
String[] strings = list.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: FYI, IntelliJ IDEA suggests to change it as `list.toArray(new String[0])`. I don't know why.

Comment: @JinKwon What is the target language version of your project?

Comment: @whirlwin 8, I believe.

Comment: Or just:  `list.toArray(String[]::new);`

Answer (score 90):

<sub>I can see many answers showing how to solve problem, but only [Stephen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5374346/1393766) is trying to explain why problem occurs so I will try to add something more on this subject. It is a story about possible reasons why `Object[] toArray` wasn't changed to `T[] toArray` where generics ware introduced to Java.</sub>

---

#### Why `String[] stockArr = (String[]) stock_list.toArray();` wont work?

In Java, ***generic type exists at compile-time only***. At runtime information about generic type (like in your case `<String>`) is removed and replaced with `Object` type (take a look at [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)). That is why at runtime `toArray()` have no idea about what precise type to use to create new array, so it uses `Object` as safest type, because each class extends Object so it can safely store instance of any class.

#### Now the problem is that you can't cast instance of `Object[]` to `String[]`.

Why? Take a look at this example (lets assume that `class B extends A`):

```
//B extends A
A a = new A();
B b = (B)a;
```

Although such code will compile, at runtime we will see thrown `ClassCastException` because instance held by reference `a` is not actually of type `B` (or its subtypes). Why is this problem (why this exception needs to be cast)? One of the reasons is that `B` could have new methods/fields which `A` doesn't, so it is possible that someone will try to use these new members via `b` reference even if held instance doesn't have (doesn't support) them. In other words we could end up trying to use data which doesn't exist, which could lead to many problems. So to prevent such situation JVM throws exception, and stop further potentially dangerous code.

You could ask now "So why aren't we stopped even earlier? Why code involving such casting is even compilable? Shouldn't compiler stop it?". Answer is: no because compiler can't know for sure what is the actual type of instance held by `a` reference, and there is a chance that it will hold instance of class `B` which will support interface of `b` reference. Take a look at this example:

```
A a = new B(); 
      //  ^------ Here reference "a" holds instance of type B
B b = (B)a;    // so now casting is safe, now JVM is sure that `b` reference can 
               // safely access all members of B class
```

---

Now lets go back to your arrays. As you see in question, we can't cast instance of `Object[]` array to more precise type `String[]` like

```
Object[] arr = new Object[] { "ab", "cd" };
String[] arr2 = (String[]) arr;//ClassCastException will be thrown
```

Here problem is a little different. Now we are sure that `String[]` array will not have additional fields or methods because every array support only:

- `[]` operator,
- `length` filed,
- methods inherited from Object supertype,

So it is *not* arrays interface which is making it impossible. Problem is that ***`Object[]` array beside `Strings` can store any objects*** (for instance `Integers`) so it is possible that one beautiful day we will end up with trying to invoke method like `strArray[i].substring(1,3)` on instance of `Integer` which doesn't have such method.

So to make *sure* that this situation will *never* happen, in Java array references can hold only

- instances of array of same type as reference (reference `String[] strArr` can hold `String[]`)
- instances of array of subtype (`Object[]` can hold `String[]` because `String` is subtype of `Object`),

but can't hold

- array of supertype of type of array from reference (`String[]` can't hold `Object[]`)
- array of type which is not related to type from reference (`Integer[]` can't hold `String[]`)

In other words something like this is OK

```
Object[] arr = new String[] { "ab", "cd" }; //OK - because
               //  ^^^^^^^^                  `arr` holds array of subtype of Object (String)
String[] arr2 = (String[]) arr; //OK - `arr2` reference will hold same array of same type as 
                                //     reference
```

---

You could say that one way to resolve this problem is to find at runtime most common type between all list elements and create array of that type, but this wont work in situations where all elements of list will be of one type derived from generic one. Take a look

```
//B extends A
List<A> elements = new ArrayList<A>();
elements.add(new B());
elements.add(new B());
```

now most common type is `B`, not `A` so `toArray()`

```
A[] arr = elements.toArray();
```

would return array of `B` class `new B[]`. Problem with this array is that while compiler would allow you to edit its content by adding `new A()` element to it, you would get `ArrayStoreException` because `B[]` array can hold only elements of class `B` or its subclass, to make sure that all elements will support interface of `B`, but instance of `A` may not have all methods/fields of `B`. So this solution is not perfect.

---

Best solution to this problem is explicitly tell what type of array `toArray()` should be returned by passing this type as method argument like

```
String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

or

```
String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[0]); //if size of array is smaller then list it will be automatically adjusted.
```

Comment: This is all correct, but the root cause of the problem is deeper / older than generic typing.  The `toArray` method has behaved like this since the collection framework was introduced.  It predates generic by a number of years.  (You could say, generics didn't fix the problem ...)

Comment: @StephenC True, I focused only at generics problem forgetting that this tool was not always part of collection framework. I will try to rewrite this answer to include your information, but can't do it not. If you have time feel free to edit it. Also feel free to down-vote it if you think I doesn't belong to this question :)

Answer (score 22):

The correct way to do this is:

```
String[] stockArr = stock_list.toArray(new String[stock_list.size()]);
```

I'd like to add to the other great answers here and explain how you could have used the Javadocs to answer your question.

The Javadoc for `toArray()` (no arguments) is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toArray%28%29). As you can see, this method returns an `Object[]` and *not* `String[]` which is an array of the runtime type of your list:

> `public Object[] toArray()`
>
> Returns an array containing all of the
>   elements in this collection. If the collection makes any guarantees as
>   to what order its elements are returned by its iterator, this method
>   must return the elements in the same order. The returned array will be
>   "safe" in that no references to it are maintained by the collection.
>   (In other words, this method must allocate a new array even if the
>   collection is backed by an Array). The caller is thus free to modify
>   the returned array.

Right below that method, though, is [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) for `toArray(T[] a)`. As you can see, this method returns a `T[]` where `T` is the type of the array you pass in. At first this seems like what you're looking for, but it's unclear exactly why you're passing in an array (are you adding to it, using it for just the type, etc). The documentation makes it clear that the purpose of the passed array is essentially to define the type of array to return (which is exactly your use case):

> `public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`
>
> Returns an array containing all of the
>   elements in this collection; **the runtime type of the returned array is
>   that of the specified array.** If the collection fits in the specified
>   array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, a new array is allocated
>   with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of this
>   collection. If the collection fits in the specified array with room to
>   spare (i.e., the array has more elements than the collection), the
>   element in the array immediately following the end of the collection
>   is set to null. This is useful in determining the length of the
>   collection only if the caller knows that the collection does not
>   contain any null elements.)
>
> If this collection makes any guarantees as to what order its elements
>   are returned by its iterator, this method must return the elements in
>   the same order.
>
> This implementation checks if the array is large enough to contain the
>   collection; if not, it allocates a new array of the correct size and
>   type (using reflection). Then, it iterates over the collection,
>   storing each object reference in the next consecutive element of the
>   array, starting with element 0. If the array is larger than the
>   collection, a null is stored in the first location after the end of
>   the collection.

Of course, an understanding of generics (as described in the other answers) is required to really understand the difference between these two methods. Nevertheless, if you first go to the Javadocs, you will usually find your answer and then see for yourself what else you need to learn (if you really do).

Also note that reading the Javadocs here helps you to understand what the structure of the array you pass in should be. Though it may not really practically matter, you should not pass in an empty array like this:

```
String [] stockArr = stockList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Because, from the doc, this implementation checks if the array is large enough to contain the collection; *if not, it allocates a new array of the correct size and type (using reflection).* There's no need for the extra overhead in creating a new array when you could easily pass in the size.

As is usually the case, the Javadocs provide you with a wealth of information and direction.

Hey wait a minute, what's reflection?

Comment: Object[] obj = stock_list.toArray();

Comment: @QuanNguyen: What are you saying? What point are you trying to make?

Comment: `toArray(new String[0])` is faster: http://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/