# how to get file path from sd card in android

Tags: android

hi all i have mp3 files in sd card. how to get file path of mp3 song from sd card.

please assist me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location  . . . .hope this link will help

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can get the path of sdcard from this code:

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Then specify the foldername and file name

for e.g:

```
"/LazyList/"+serialno.get(position).trim()+".jpg"
```

Comment: There is a buildin storage which is /storage/sdcard0 and an SD card  which is /storage/sdcard1 in my phone( running android 4.1.2.) The Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() return /storage/sdcard0. Is there any way to get the path of SD card which is /storage/sdcard1? Hard code it?

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns "/storage/emulated/0", while my SDCard actually lives at "/storage/extSdCard/"

Answer (score 18):

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will **NOT** return path to **micro SD card Storage**.

> how to get file path from sd card in android

By *sd card*, I am assuming that, you meant *removable micro SD card*.

In API level 19 i.e. in Android version 4.4 Kitkat, they have added `File[] getExternalFilesDirs (String type)` in `Context` Class that allows apps to store data/files in micro SD cards.

Android 4.4 is the first release of the platform that has actually allowed apps to use SD cards for storage. Any access to SD cards before **API level 19** was through private, unsupported APIs.

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` was there from **API level 1**

[getExternalFilesDirs(String type)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)) returns absolute paths to application-specific directories on all shared/external storage devices. It means, it will return paths to both internal and external memory. Generally, **second returned path** would be the storage path for microSD card (if any).

But note that,

> Shared storage may not always be available, since removable media can
>   be ejected by the user. Media state can be checked using
>   `getExternalStorageState(File)`.
>
> There is no security enforced with these files. For example, any
>   application holding `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` can write to these files.

The Internal and External Storage **terminology** according to Google/official Android docs is **quite different** from what we think.

Comment: interesting answer, but you should, for completeness, include the class that your method getExternalFilesDirs  exists in. dv for incompleteness.

Comment: @bharal that's why I provided a hyperlink. when user clicks, it redirects to android official documentation which has all the details

Answer (score 12):

this code helps to get it easily............

Actually in some devices external sdcard default name is showing as extSdCard and for other it is sdcard1. This code snippet helps to find out that exact path and helps to retrive you the path of external device..

```
String sdpath,sd1path,usbdiskpath,sd0path; 

if(new File("/storage/extSdCard/").exists()) 
{ 
  sdpath="/storage/extSdCard/";
  Log.i("Sd Cardext Path",sdpath); 
} 
if(new File("/storage/sdcard1/").exists()) 
{ 
  sd1path="/storage/sdcard1/";
  Log.i("Sd Card1 Path",sd1path); 
} 
if(new File("/storage/usbcard1/").exists()) 
{ 
  usbdiskpath="/storage/usbcard1/";
  Log.i("USB Path",usbdiskpath); 
} 
if(new File("/storage/sdcard0/").exists()) 
{ 
  sd0path="/storage/sdcard0/";
  Log.i("Sd Card0 Path",sd0path); 
}
```

Comment: Nice workaround, are these all possible names for sd card?

Comment: @SamvelKartashyan Sure not! :) For example, we had a device where the SD card was mounted on `"/storage/ext_sd/"`, and another where it is in "/mnt/sdcard/"

Answer (score 3):

By using the following code you can find name, path, size as like this all kind of information of all audio song files

```
String[] STAR = { "*" };     
Uri allaudiosong = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String audioselection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
Cursor cursor;
cursor = managedQuery(allaudiosong, STAR, audioselection, null, null);

if (cursor != null) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String song_name = cursor
                   .getString(cursor
                             .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
            System.out.println("Audio Song Name= "+song_name);

            int song_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
            System.out.println("Audio Song ID= "+song_id);

            String fullpath = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            System.out.println("Audio Song FullPath= "+fullpath);

            String album_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            System.out.println("Audio Album Name= "+album_name);

            int album_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
            System.out.println("Audio Album Id= "+album_id);

            String artist_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            System.out.println("Audio Artist Name= "+artist_name);

            int artist_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID));
            System.out.println("Audio Artist ID= "+artist_id);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 1):

As some people indicated, the officially accepted answer does not quite return the external removable SD card. And i ran upon the following thread that proposes a method I've tested on some Android devices and seems to work reliably, so i thought of re-sharing here as i don't see it in the other responses:

http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s7/668364-whats-external-sdcard-path.html

Kudos to paresh996 for coming up with the answer itself, and i can attest I've tried on Samsung S7 and S7edge and seems to work.

Now, i needed a method that returned a valid path where to read files, and that considered the fact that there might not be an external SD, in which case the internal storage should be returned, so i modified the code from paresh996 to this :

```
File getStoragePath() {
    String removableStoragePath;
    File fileList[] = new File("/storage/").listFiles();
    for (File file : fileList) {
       if(!file.getAbsolutePath().equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()) && file.isDirectory() && file.canRead()) {
            return file;
        }
    }
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are having the same problem i had, my tablet has a SD card on it, in /mnt/sdcard and the sd card external was in /mnt/extcard, you can look it on the android file manager, going to your sd card and see the path to it.

Hope it helps.