# Reading a certificate file(.cer) from sd card in android

Tags: java, android, certificate

I have copied my certificate file(x.cer) into my emulator sdcard. Now I want to send that certificate from my android client to the Server.
Earlier I used to do this by putting the certificate into the keystore and then putting the keystore in the sdcard. The keystore class has a function **getCertificate(alias)**. 
 Now I want to read the certificate directly as I have only copied the certificate and not the keystore. How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

```
CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("path")));
```

should do it.

How to get hold of the SD card path is described here:

[how to get file path from sd card in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858107/how-to-get-file-path-from-sd-card-in-android)