# android loading image from sd card into db

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite

I need to create a view to select a photo and store that photo in my local db.

I have tried:

```
private final int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;
```

In a button I put:

```
Intent i = new Intent(
Intent.ACTION_PICK,
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_IMAGE);
```

But when I select the picture, the intent close and dont return to my apk.
Some here, my intent is finish. And the `onActivityResult` never runs. So, i can't handler...

My `onActivityResult` is this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode){
            case SELECT_IMAGE:
                if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                }
        }
    }
```

And to help, on LogCat I have NOTHING. Amazing...

I am using apk on API 7.

Comment: I try this two links...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062150/trying-to-load-an-image-from-sdcard-on-android?rq=1
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/23/store-image-android-sqlite-retrieve-it/

but nothing...

Comment: I again...  
I solve my problem...  
In manifest i have the activity how handler that code with some extra options...like:  
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
Cant use that options in this activity...  
DONE!!!  
I houp this info help some one too...
;)  
Sory my write...