# Read file from root folder on Android

Tags: java, android, file

My Android application needs to read a CSV file which is copied to the root directory on the device (device is NOT rooted so I guess it's not the real root directory, just the directory you see when opening the device in Windows explorer).

I wonder if this is possible?

When I do this:

```
File file = new File("/data.csv");

if (file.exists()) {
    System.out.println("File exists!");
} else {
    System.out.println("File does NOT exist");
}
```

I get: "File does NOT exist"

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5858161/1404734

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
`File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/data.csv");`
Make sure you include the proper READ permissions(depending on the API level you are targeting) in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Change getDataDirectory to getExternalStorageDirectory

Comment: Thanks! I thought getExternalStorageDirectory was for the SD card and not for the internal storage.

Comment: glad I could help :) take a look at this link: https://source.android.com/devices/storage/