# Reading Text file in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read a text file stored in my mobile device external storage , but it is throwing this error: -
   **Error occured while reading text file!!/storage/emulated/0/atom.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)**
Here's the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_picker);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                fileOpener();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void fileOpener() throws IOException {
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //Get the text file
    File file = new File(sdcard,"atom.txt");
    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {

        Log.e("Error", "Error occured while reading text file!!" + e.getMessage());
    }

    //Find the view by its id
  Log.d("Text",text.toString());
}
```

}

How can I figure this out?
**EDIT : The atom.txt file is already saved in my device but still it is throwing the same error.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23737335/1320704

Answer (score 0):

The file doesn't exist, so the path returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory` is not what you are expecting it to be. According to the [API docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()), this path is not guaranteed to be an SD card.

Comment: Ok i get it what you just said , but can you please tell me what changes should i do in above code in order to run it properly . It would be helpful for me.