# Android Studio not adding Imports, cannot find Import for File class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to add a line of code to get the path to external storage directory
`File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`

However, I cannot figure out what I need to Import to get the `File` and `Environment` objects

Android studio is not automatically adding it as I expected

Searching online, I cannot find anywhere what I need to import

How am I supposed to know this?

Stack Overflow answers like this do not provide the required Imports to make it work

[how to get file path from sd card in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858107/how-to-get-file-path-from-sd-card-in-android)

Comment: The imports are `import java.io.File; import android.os.Environment;`.   You can look them up via the Android javadocs: use Google to find them.

Comment: And to diagnose problems with android studio not being able to find imports read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688.

Comment: "How am I supposed to know this?" - Googling for "android javadoc file" gives me https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File as the first search result.   So maybe the trick is to improve your searching technique ...