# External Sd Card (external memory) in Android?

Tags: android

There are three types of memory in the android:

+Internal Memory (DONE)

+SdCard (DONE)

+External Sd Card (external memory card -  external storage (FLASH)): How to get total size of it's and How to identify the external_sdcard directory in android??
Hope soon to get answers :)

Comment: I thought SdCard is External storage not memory.  I think you are getting memory and disk space confused.

Comment: Thanks! I have found the solution

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049114/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-does-not-return-the-path-to-the-removable

Answer (score 1):

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long bytesCount = (long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getBlockCount();
return bytesCount;
```

Comment: Thanks! I have found the solution

Answer (score 0):

If `Environment.getExternalStorage...` is not working, use:

```
StatFs statFs = new StatFs(System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE"));
float total_space = ((float)statFs.getBlockCount() * statFs.getBlockSize()) / 1048576;

// This will give in mega bytes.
```

Enjoy. Hope this is helpful.

```
// For internal storage use this> System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
```