# Browsing for a file and uploading it to server through socket

Tags: android, sockets, file-upload, file-browser

I am developing an application which enables user to browse for a file in the storage (internal / external) and upload it to the java Serversocket.

Thank you.

Here is my file chooser code

```
public String fileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("file/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Your File"), 1);


}
```

Application keeps crashing..... what am I doing wrong?
Okay I figured it out the app was crashing because I was trying to return URI in the method itself. Then I modified it so that it could be obtained when user selects a file from the picker.

However now I am hosting a Socket server Which will receive the file (any file text/ multimedia) and store it into a particular directory.

My Receiver as follows:

```
public void step1()
{
   File theDir = new File("C://ServerFiles");
     if (!theDir.exists()) {
    try{
        theDir.mkdir();

     } catch(SecurityException se){
        areaStatus.append("error creating file \n");
     }        
  }

      try {
                    InetAddress IP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                    lblIp.setText("IP:"+IP.toString());
                } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ServerConfig.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
        try {
            areaStatus.append("ServerRunning.... \n");
            String SPort;
            SPort = txtport.getText();
            Serverport  =Integer.parseInt(SPort);
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Serverport);

             ClientSocket=serverSocket.accept();
            areaStatus.append("Connected With"+ClientSocket.getInetAddress().toString()+"\n");

             input = ClientSocket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClientSocket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter outReader = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ClientSocket.getOutputStream()));

            filename = inReader.readLine();

            if ( !filename.equals("") ){



                outReader.write("READY\n");
                outReader.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerConfig.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

areaStatus.append("Client connected \n");   


}

public void step2()
{
     byte[] buffer;
     buffer= null;
    FileOutputStream wr = null;

        try {
            wr = new FileOutputStream(new File("C://ServerFiles/" + filename));
        try {
            buffer = new byte[ClientSocket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerConfig.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
            int bytesReceived = 0;
        try {
            while((bytesReceived = input.read(buffer))>0)
            {
                /* Write to the file */
                wr.write(buffer,0,bytesReceived);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerConfig.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            wr.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerConfig.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        areaStatus.append("Transfer completed \n");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerConfig.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                wr.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(ServerConfig.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

}
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        step1();           

    }                              


        }
    }
```

I am working on file sender I'll post as soon as I'm done.

This is my file sender but it is showing File not found error:

```
 private class Fileuploader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Socket sk;

            try {
                sk = new Socket("192.168.0.108", 1131);

                File myFile = new File(filepathString);
                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

                OutputStream os = sk.getOutputStream();

                os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

                os.flush();

                sk.close();




            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




            return 1;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        }
    }
```

My ADB log:

```
04-22 13:23:14.269    8355-8385/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-22 13:23:14.299    8355-8385/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-22 13:23:16.860    8355-8355/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-22 13:23:24.745    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Atext%2Fmessenger_dndictionary.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-22 13:23:24.757    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
04-22 13:23:24.757    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
04-22 13:23:24.757    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ at envoyone.ak.ace.fileud.FileUpload$Fileuploader.doInBackground(FileUpload.java:98)
04-22 13:23:24.757    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ at envoyone.ak.ace.fileud.FileUpload$Fileuploader.doInBackground(FileUpload.java:78)
04-22 13:23:24.757    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-22 13:23:24.757    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-22 13:23:24.757    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-22 13:23:24.759    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-22 13:23:24.759    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-22 13:23:24.759    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-22 13:23:24.759    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-22 13:23:24.760    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
04-22 13:23:24.760    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
04-22 13:23:24.760    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
04-22 13:23:24.760    8355-8387/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/System.err﹕ ... 9 more
04-22 13:23:54.924    8355-8355/envoyone.ak.ace.fileud W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gallery items are just images and videos.
You have a couple of options here.

1)Use another app to pick the file

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

This will open a list of apps that can browse files. A file can be chosen from that interface

2)Use Storage Access Framework. It is similar to point 1. But the interface  is provided by android itself. [Read more](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html)

3)Use a `File` object to access external storage directory. The following permission must be added in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then the following will give a file object pointing to the primary external storage directory, from which entire file system can be accessed.

```
File file = new File(Environment. getExternalStorageDirectory ());
```

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

To access files from removable microSD card, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716448/how-to-access-external-micro-sd-card-of-the-phone) answer

Comment: Hi Akash thanks for the reply. I tried the SAF and i was able to go to a file picker, but soon after I press the button application crashes.