# Permission Denial：broadcasting Intent is not exported

Tags: android

I have the following codes:

`sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath())));`

And in my manifest, I have added:

```
           <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I receive the following error

```
07-20 13:16:31.203: WARN/BroadcastQueue(395): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED dat=file:///storage/sdcard0 flg=0x10 } from com.example.Music_Exchanger (pid=11797, uid=10080) is not exported from uid 10016 due to receiver com.android.providers.downloads/com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadReceiver
```

I don't know why it will be denial. And how can I solve it???

If you know, please help me, and please write more detailed. I am just a beginner.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement broadcast receiver and add it's definition to the manifest file:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <!--...-->

    <receiver
        android:name=".CustomReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Where CustomReciever extends BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: How did you fix this issue? What did you add in CustomReciever?

Answer (score 1):

add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/>
```

another note: write external storage implicity has read external storage permission.

Answer (score 0):

Use MediaScannerConnection  instead of SendBroadcast..

```
conn = new MediaScannerConnection( * * your context * * ,
     new MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient() {@
         Override
         public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

             if (path.equals( * * your filename * * .getAbsolutePath())) {
                 Log.i("Scan Status", "Completed");
                 Log.i("uri: ", uri.toString());

                 conn.disconnect();
             }
         }@
         Override
         public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             conn.scanFile( * * your file name * * .getAbsolutePath(), null);

         }
     });
 conn.connect();
```