# Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I have created a simple camera app. It works fine in all the versions of Android except Android 4.4. I get the following error when I take a picture from my camera App.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=26089, uid=10120
```

Error comes up:

In the following place:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

How to fix this issue for KITKAT?

Let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Might be worth your time reading other posts like this one.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759041/permission-denialbroadcasting-intent-is-not-exported

Answer (score 20):

> How to fix this issue for KITKAT?

That code has never been appropriate. Fortunately, Android is (finally) taking steps to prevent apps from spoofing more system broadcasts like this.

If you want to tell Android to index a file you put on external storage, either use [`MediaScannerConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) or [`ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE).

Comment: I tried using MediaScannerConnection like this http://pastebin.com/Fve98x6s and its working in kitkat device, but not working in android 4.3 & below devices.

Comment: @AndroidDev: I have had no problems with `MediaScannerConnection` on older Android devices.

Comment: @AndroidDev Did it work for you on android 4.3 and below devices?

Answer (score 10):

I resolved this problem, you can use this:

`sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, mediaMountUri));`

hope this  can help you !

Comment: Doesn’t work for me with just the media root path. You need to pass the URI of the actual file that changed, and only that file will be scanned.

Answer (score 5):

Android prevents apps from sending broadcast like ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE or ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED.
Use static method scanFile of MediaScannerConnection instead.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath() }, null, new OnScanCompletedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Comment: This worked for me to get images to show in the gallery. Thanks Yvan.

Comment: `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` got locked down in KitKat. `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` is still allowed and does essentially the same as your code, with the same restriction of scanning a single file only. Main differences with the intent: no callback, and the scan will finish even if the process ends before it does (unlike with a `MediaScannerConnection`).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't, at least not easily.

A lot of apps used to use this intent to rescan the entire filesystem after changing only one file, which drained battery life considerably. Starting from Android 4.4, only System apps can now use it.  You'll likely have to find a workaround that doesn't use this intent.

Comment: Can you give me a work around? I couldn't figure out a work around?