# securityexception permission denial not allowed to send broadcast

Tags: android

My application on  other version it work fine but on `KitKat` my applicatin crash on calling time give me error: `securityexception permission denial not allowed to send broadcast`.

Please tell me how can resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

```
How to fix this issue for KITKAT?
```

That code has never been appropriate. Fortunately, Android is (finally) taking steps to prevent apps from spoofing more system broadcasts like this.

```
If you want to tell Android to index a file you put on external storage, either use MediaScannerConnection or ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE.
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21469533/1683141

Comment: Please publish the source when you copy an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21469533/1683141

Comment: Like the edit shows you: just paste the link into your answer.

Comment: Even better: flag the question as a duplicate!