# Not Allowed To Send Broadcast in Android

Tags: android

I've written a code that opens a file in another app. For some reason I am getting this error. I've been using two devices; a tablet with 4.2.2 and a phone with 4.4.2.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=26089, uid=10120
```

My code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(file.toString()));
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file.toString()), file.getMimeType());
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Also to mention, there's this code, but I am not using it when the error appears. It doesn't work even after I delete this code.

```
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469431/permission-denial-not-allowed-to-send-broadcast-in-android)

Comment: Duplicate issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469431/permission-denial-not-allowed-to-send-broadcast-in-android

Comment: Yes, I've googled it, but there is no solution.