# App Working Perfect with Android 4.2.2 but not with 4.4.4

Tags: android, performance, camera, crash, gps

I am kinda new to App development and working on my first app, which is taking a burst mode of pictures with the current gps coordinates attached to each picture.

I was trying this app with my Sony Xperia L with JellyBean 4.2.2 and it takes burst shots of any number I have input. I tried to run my App in 4.4.4 and it runs basically, open the number of cameras, but i click to 'take' picture, my app crashes.

NOTE:

Behind this take picture button is kinda loads of work loadI know it sounds stupid to put up all things in main activity, but i dont know how to take off the load.

The fact is its running on 4.2.2 as expected (with many errors in LOGCAT but still running cool) and it crashes when i click 'Snap' in 4.4.4.

in main activity, I am taking jpeg PictureCallBacks and put up the gps listener, pushing to make a photofile with the EXIF DATA embedded and all in MAIN ACTIVITY. here is the picture

[image]

Comment: What's the exception you are getting? Post the logcat

Comment: check I added the pic @Blacklight .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to use the `android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED` broadcast anymore on Android 4.4, it's protected. Try to use [ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE) instead.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469431/permission-denial-not-allowed-to-send-broadcast-in-android), or also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072489/java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-not-allowed-to-send-broadcast-an).

Comment: okay thanks for sharing this. I changed this object and app is not crashing now. Thanks.

Comment: BTW I am looking to offload my gps jpeg callbacks code ~ any good suggestions?

Comment: Not really without seeing the code, sorry, that would be beyond the scope of this question. You could post another one, explaining your current architecture concisely though.