# Android studio how delete downloaded files parse?

Tags: file, gridview, android-studio, parse-platform, android-sdcard

I am new in android studio and I am using Parse to store images. I am creating an image gallery and I am able to display downloaded images from parse to gridview. The problem is everytime I restart the app, my SDcard will download the exact same files from Parse. Is there a way to delete these unnecessary files? Or how can I put these Downloaded image files into a temporary storage where they will be deleted once the user is finished with the app?
This is my code for downloading the images and store them in gridview:

```
        for (ParseObject imageOb : objects) {
                            final ParseFile file = (ParseFile) imageOb.get("image");

                            file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {

                                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                                        Uri uri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bitmap);

                                        File imageFiles = new File(getRealPathFromURI(uri));

                                        imageAdapter.add(imageFiles.toString());

                                    }

                                    imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }

                            });

                        }
```

Comment: You should try to avoid that many levels of brackets, the code becomes hard to read. The first two if statements can be combined into a single if statement.

Comment: okay David, i will edit it

Comment: Did you search Stack Overflow for similar questions? This looks like it might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317934/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-temporary-files-on-android

Did you try manually deleting the files when the user is finished with your application?

Comment: @David  it still failing. thanks for the suggestion though. i think the solution to my problem is just to get the image url and display it to my gridView then onDestroy, i delete all of the image URL ?

Comment: Yeah, but you don't specify in which part of the Android lifecycle you add the image. If you do it in `onStart`, `onDestroy` is fine; but if you download the images in `onResume` you should delete them in `onPause`. Check out this article on the Android lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Comment: @David aahh i see i see... i added the image inside onCreate. will it work?

Comment: I think it should work as you expect.

Comment: @David allright i'll try that

Answer (score 0):

There are some answers already on Stack overflow about temporary files, for example [What is the best way to create temporary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317934/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-temporary-files-on-android)

You could also manually delete the downloaded files when the application doesn't need them anymore. If you download them in `onCreate` you should delete them in `onDestroy`. Otherwise, check out this [Article about the Android lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)