# How to get the exact path of file stored in internal storage from different tablets?

Tags: java, android

I want to get the **filename** stored in documents folder.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/documents/"+Abc.doc;
```

To get the filename, I had hardcoded the path using `substring(11, path.length())`. It works 
fine only for specific tablets, but its not working for some tablets. 
How do I get **filename** without hardcoding the path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049114/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-does-not-return-the-path-to-the-removabl 
This is an iffy topic since different tablets have different meanings to whats internal and what is external storage while Android has one definition

Comment: Also look at @commonsware answer here to get an idea of this concept http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location/5695129#5695129