# Why does getExternalStorageDirectory return my phone's root storage, not the SD card?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read from a folder on my phone's SD card with a path `\weights\input`. Android's `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()` returns `/storage/emulated/0`, and `isDirectory()` for that path returns true. But when I execute the following code:

```
File weights = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
List<File> inputs = getListFiles(weights);
```

the list `inputs` contains all the files on my phone's internal storage, not the SD card, so when I look for a directory in `inputs`, my app fails.

Why is this? BTW, I am completely an Android and Java novice. Completely.

Comment: Try appending `/weights/input/`

Comment: Just an hour ago I had the same problem and tried randomly adding `/` and it worked!

Comment: Can you mention how many files are there in the directory?

Comment: 13 files, but that number is variable. What does that matter?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and I tried appending `/` at the end. You can try following:

```
/weights/input/
```

instead of

```
/weights/input
```

**EDIT:**
After you edit, I found this:

> `getExternalStorageDirectory` is implemented to return whatever is set
>   as "external storage" in the device environment:
>
> ```
> public static File getExternalStorageDirectory() {
>     return EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY;
> }
> ```
>
> and `EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY` is:
>
> ```
> private static final File EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY = getDirectory("EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "/sdcard");
>
> static File getDirectory(String variableName, String defaultPath) {
>     String path = System.getenv(variableName);
>     return path == null ? new File(defaultPath) : new File(path);
> }
> ```
>
> In contrast, `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type)` requires
>   one of these strings:
>
> > DIRECTORY_MUSIC, DIRECTORY_PODCASTS, DIRECTORY_RINGTONES, DIRECTORY_ALARMS, DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS, DIRECTORY_PICTURES,
> >     DIRECTORY_MOVIES, DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, or DIRECTORY_DCIM. **May not be
> >     null.**
>
> so it is not meant to return the sd-card root.
>
> **An alternative:**
>
> Finally, `getExternalStorageState()` will return the filesystem
>   mounted in `/mnt/sdcard/`. According to CommonsWare in this answer:
>   [Find an external SD card location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location/5695129#5695129), there is no way to directly
>   get the external sdcard (if it even exist).
>
> An alternative would be to check `isExternalStorageRemovable ()` and
>   give a **manual option if it is false**.

Source: [This link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049114/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-does-not-return-the-path-to-the-removabl)

Comment: Very sorry, that was a mistake. The / at the end somehow gets stripped off, and `isDirectory` still returns false.

Comment: But this worked perfectly fine in my case. wait i'll tell what I've done in my project.

Comment: Hey, have you added permissions in menifest? You have to give permission to read your external storage. This could be the reason why it is giving false.

Comment: Yes, I have: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: What is the file name which you want to read from that directory? And are you sure `input` is a directory? If yes, than see edits.

Comment: I want to list files in that directory. I don't know their names.