# Writing .txt file on android - nothing happens

Tags: java, android, file, android-external-storage

I have an android app which is recording audio and outputting it withe the name audiorecorder to the local storage on the phone.
Now i would like store a .txt file as well in same directory.

I have tried several methods from stack overflow, the app doesn't complain but does not store the .txt as it should. I can't figure out why.

The methods of interest is: CreateTxt and generateNote. These are the ones that doesn't do what they are supposed to.

These methods are used within the startR.setOnClickListener method.

Can anybody see why? Thank you in advance.

```
package xxxx;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import static android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;

public class DataCollectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPLayer;
    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    private String OUTPUT_FILE;

    public Button GoToUserAcc;
    public Button GoToLogin;
    public Button GoToTest;

    // Permission Variables
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 200;
    private static String mFileName = null;
    private boolean permissionToRecordAccepted = false;
    private String [] permissions = 
    {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, 
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
    Manifest.permission.INTERNET};

    private static final int 
    REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 200;
    private boolean permissionToWriteExternalStoragedAccepted = 
    false;

    private static final int REQUEST_INTERNET_PERMISSION = 200;
    private boolean permissionToUseInternetAccepted = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_collec);


        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Button startR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bstart);
        Button stopR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bstop);
        Button playRecording = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
        Button stopPlaying = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopBtn);
        final TextView statusTV;
        statusTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tStatus);

        OUTPUT_FILE= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
        getAbsolutePath()+"/audiorecorder.3gpp";


        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, 
        REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);

        /*------START recording BUTTON------*/

        startR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final TextView stv=statusTV;
                try {
                    beginRecording();
                    stv.setText("Recording");
                    //CreateTxt();
                    generateNote("MLdata", "sBody");
                    stv.setText("Created txt");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                    String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
                    stv.setText("Error");
                }
            }
        });

        /*------STOP BUTTON------*/

        stopR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final TextView stv=statusTV;
                try {
                    stopRecording();
                    stv.setText("Stopped");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                    String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
                    statusTV.setText("Error");
                    Log.d("here","dd",e);
                }
            }
        });


    }

    private void stopPlayback() throws Exception{
        if(mediaPLayer != null)
            mediaPLayer.stop();
    }
    private void playRecording() throws IOException {
        ditchMediaPLayer();
        mediaPLayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPLayer.setDataSource(OUTPUT_FILE);
        mediaPLayer.prepare();
        mediaPLayer.start();

    }

    private void ditchMediaPLayer() {
        if (mediaPLayer != null) {
            try{
                mediaPLayer.release();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        if(recorder != null)
            recorder.stop();
    }
    private void beginRecording() throws Exception{
        ditchMediaRecorder();
        File outFile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);
        //DataCollectionActivity dca = new DataCollectionActivity();
        //dca.CreateTxt();
        if (outFile.exists()) {
            outFile.delete();
        }

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.
        OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);

        /*API constraints
        Container   WAV
        Encoding    PCM
        Rate    16K
        Sample Format   16 bit    OK
        Channels    Mono         OK
         */
        recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16);
        //channel 1 equals mono, 2 eqals stereo
        recorder.setAudioChannels(1);

        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }

    private void ditchMediaRecorder() {
        if(recorder != null)
            recorder.release();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_setting){
            Toast.makeText(DataCollectionActivity.this, "You have 
      clicked on setting action menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_about_us){
            Toast.makeText(DataCollectionActivity.this, "You have 
       clicked on about us action menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            goToUserAccount();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Requesting permission to RECORD_AUDIO
    //fra android.com


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull 
    String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
    grantResults);

        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION:
                permissionToRecordAccepted  = grantResults[0] == 
     PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                break;
        }
        if (!permissionToRecordAccepted ) finish();

        //---ny permission ---
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
        grantResults);
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION:
                permissionToWriteExternalStoragedAccepted  = 
        grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                break;
        }
        if (!permissionToRecordAccepted ) finish();

        //---ny permission ---
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
         grantResults);
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_INTERNET_PERMISSION:
                permissionToUseInternetAccepted  = grantResults[0] == 
         PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                break;
        }
        if (!permissionToRecordAccepted ) finish();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater mMenuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        mMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Opens up new activity */
    //Vedrører tollbaren som ligenu ikke bliver brugt /virker ikke.
    public void goToUserAccount() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserAccountActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) 
    findViewById(R.id.action_about_us);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    //Metode som laver en writer.
    public void CreateTxt() throws  IOException {
        //concerning txt file
        int id = 0;
        String typeId = "S";

        EditText db = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dbNoiseText);
        String dbString = db.getText().toString();

        EditText numPar = (EditText) 
        findViewById(R.id.participatorsText);
        String npar = numPar.getText().toString();

        EditText conversationBool = (EditText) 
        findViewById(R.id.CoverationText);
        String cBool = conversationBool.getText().toString();

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
        getAbsolutePath()+"dataForML.txt");
        try {
            System.out.print("enters try in createtxt");
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(f, "UTF-8");
            writer.println(dbString + ", ");
            writer.println(npar + ", ");
            writer.println(cBool + ", ");
            writer.println(typeId + id + ", ");
            writer.println(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
            getAbsolutePath()+"/dataForML.txt");
            //Her skal den skrive binary. Metoden ligger i asrRequest
            writer.println("Path to Acceleroeter CSV file ");
            writer.println("\n");
            writer.println();
            writer.close();
            id++;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //OUTPUT_FILE= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
    getAbsolutePath()+"/audiorecorder.3gpp";

    //generateNoteOnSD("MLdata", "sBody");
    public void generateNote(String sFileName, String sBody) {
        try {
            File root = new 
            File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
            getAbsolutePath(), "NotesML");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            writer.append(sBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void thirdTry(){
        String FILENAME = "hello_file";
        String string = "hello world!";
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, 
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(string.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}


layout xml comes here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dbNoiseText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="db noise"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/participatorsText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="# participators"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/CoverationText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Conversation? Y/N"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Bstart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Start Recording" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Bstop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Stop recording" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tStatus"
        android:layout_width="354dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:text="status"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>

Manifest comes here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="dk.itu.percomp17.jumanji">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" 
/>
    <uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category 
android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".UserAccountActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".DataCollectionActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".CallingjsActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: try solutions provided in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049114/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-does-not-return-the-path-to-the-removabl

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`. Please put Toasts in those catch blocks to inform the user. And yourself.

Comment: I think you are missing / in these lines      File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
        getAbsolutePath()+"/dataForML.txt");

Comment: You are right. I think that was an issue too. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. Following method solved it.

```
// Once a file has been created, use this method to publicize
//the file as it can be seen !!
// But be sure to add "Context context;" outside of the method.
// Plus, remember to add "context = getApplicationContext ();" in the 
//onCreate () method.

public void scanFile(String path) {

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[] { path }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Finished scanning " + path);
                }
            });
}
```