# java.io.fileNotFoundException(Permission denied)

Tags: android, exception, permissions, ioexception

I have the next method :

```
public void saveOnSDCard() {
    File path = new File("storage/sdcard1");

    File dir = new File(path + "");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(dir, "test.png");

    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        showToast("Ошибка " + ioe.toString());
    }
}
```

but when i try to call it, it gives me a java.io.fileNotFoundException(Permission denied).
I have the next permission in my Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So can someone tell me what's wrong ?

P.S image - Bitmap object, i declared it in another method.

Comment: What is the API version or android os version u are trying this

Comment: @Psypher i tried this code on API 19 and API 25. Both doesn't work

Comment: can you debug the method and get the path of the "path", "dir" and "file" objects?

Comment: @GiulioPettenuzzo Already

Comment: @ Максим Коваль post your error log so that it will be easy to detect issue and if you are trying to run this code sdk >=23 then you have to add runtime permisions to access external storage

Comment: the code not able to create to directory and you have not given the folder name also.so you are getting the `java.io.fileNotFoundException(Permission denied)`

Comment: If you want to use external storage means your removable sdcard then diff devices shows different sdcard path such as  `/mnt/m_external_sd/` or  `/storage/sdcard1/` you can get your attached device  sdcard path in android studio IDE **View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer** so instead of using sdcard use internal storage simply by using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for reference you can use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049114/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-does-not-return-the-path-to-the-removabl/6049446#6049446

Comment: @userI When i use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), i get the internal storage path

Comment: try to use "/mnt/external_sd/" but it will differ from device to device

Comment: @userI I have another path to my external storage

Comment: what path you get from  **View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer**

Comment: @userI /storage/sdcard1

Comment: File path = new File("storage/sdcard1");
if(path.exists()){ Log.i("path is",path)} else {System.out.println("path not found");} try this code and tell me the output

Comment: @userI i get : "path is storage/sdcard1"

Comment: from sdcard path you are having readonly permission thats why you are unable to write to sdcard

Comment: @userI How can i get the permission to write to sdcard? Is it possible?

Comment: from version kitkat onwards you have a permission to only read from sdcard.But is there any particular reason to use sdcard only instead of internal storage?

Comment: @userI So as i understood if i have an android version 4.4+, i can't write to sdcard?

Comment: But if you make your sdcard as primary memory i.e format as internal storage then you can able to write to that storage

Comment: @userI Yes, u'r right, i tried it. Thanks a lot for help and for information.

Answer (score 0):

try if one of the following solutions works:

1. replace `"storage/sdcard1"` with`"storage/sdcard1/"`
2. replace `path + ""` with `path + "/"`
3. replace `"test.png"` with `"/test.png"`

I think it's just missing a slash in one of those three lines

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

Guy in comment told me that if you have an android 4.4+ you can write to sdcard only when you make your sdcard as primary memory or sometimes when ur phone is rooted. I tried it and it really works.