# Use BitmapFactory.decodeFile() but image is not Decoded

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

My Problem is I am getting Image from Gallery & use BitmapFactory.decodeResource() for Convert the image into bitmap but the Problem is the Image is get in Emulator but not in Real Device, In Real Device the Bitmap value is getting null. following is my code for decode Gallery Image.

```
String Galleryimagepath="/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails/1308059312410.jpg";     
bmpImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Galleryimagepath);
drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmpImage);
mRlayoutmainimage.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you getting image from the thumbnails folder and not the actual folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yashwanth is right, the path may be different between device and emulator, further, the path may different device to device as well.  You'd be better off getting a content URI for the image you want and using MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail() to get the bitmap you're looking for.

[MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think sd card path on real device is different. you might have to use something like

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState()
```

check the following link.

[Find an external SD card location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)

Comment: I get "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails/1308059312410.jpg" path from Gallery Intent.