# How to find Internal(Default Phone Storage ) and External Storage(Removable sd card) in android?

Tags: java, android, storage, sd-card, data-storage

My Motorola Phone has 12GB internal storage and Removable Sd card feature.

In DDMS file explorer my **internal phone storage(12GB) is mounted as sdcard** and **my removable sdcard is mounted as sdcard-ext**.

Using "**Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()**" method i can able to get the directory "**/mnt/sdcard**". 
Is there is any method through which i can find the absolute path of my removable sdcard?... ie.,which will return me "**/mnt/sdcard-ext**"

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114901/how-to-read-from-the-internal-storage-subfolder-download-of-android-android

Answer (score 5):

The Android framework currently supports only one mass storage device, so it's hard to manage multiple *(you could try to parse `/proc/mounts` to get all mounted devices)*.
But you can use Motorolas API that they built because of that fact.

Check out the [Motorola "External" Storage API](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/motorola-external-storage-api/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code its return all storage folder name.

Check My post here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38930531/1733810

Don't forget to add permission.

Getting access to external storage

In order to read or write files on the external storage, your app must acquire the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE system permissions. For example:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```