# write file to sd card and not usb storage

Tags: android

I am developing an application that needs to write files to the SD card.  I am using GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory() to determine the directory to write to.

I have two phones I am developing with.  On a Google Nexus S, running Android 4.0.4 (Ice cream sandwich) it is returning a directory on the SD card.  However, on a Samsung Exhibit 2 running Android 2.3.5, it is writing directly to the USB storage on the phone.

Is there a way to force the SD card?

**edit:**

I found that getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(), and getExternalStorageDirectory() are always returning "/mnt/sdcard/".  This is not actually the mount location for the sd card.  On the Samsung Exhibit 2, this is the USB storage location.  The card mount location is "/mnt/sdcard/external_sd".  Is there a way to return this actual sd location?

I see that the camera and other apps have found a way to do it.  The camera app has a "storage" setting with options "phone" and "memory card".  If "memory card" is specified, images are actually stored on the sd card.

Comment: +1 "Android will run always the same on all devices", better we use "platform independent development" hahaha. Motorola Defy: sdcard-ext ( not underscore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to return this actual sd location?

No, sorry, not in the current Android SDK.

> I see that the camera and other apps have found a way to do it.

Mostly, they will either be ones written by the device manufacturer, or are reading information via `MediaStore`, which should index both sources.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to SD card only use

```
File mySdCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (mySdCardPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/yourDirectoryName");
```

Comment: The described solution has the same behavior on both phones as using GetExternalPublicDirectory("yourDirectoryName").  The directory that is returned from GetExternalStorageDirectory() is actually "/mnt/sdcard".  Apparently on the Samsung Exhibit 2, this is the USB Storage.  The actual sdcard is at "/mnt/sdcard/external_sd".  Apparently this is a known problem.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5694933/758074