# How to save file on external SDCARD on android MotorolaARTIX2 device?

Tags: android, file, save, external, sd-card

I would like to save a file on external SdCard.I have implemented an application for save a file on external sdcard.But my Android MotorolaARTIX2 device contains internal sdcard.When i am trying to save file on external sdcard it always saving to internal sdcard in my device.

I have implemented my application as follows:

```
     try {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (root.canWrite()){
            File file = new File(root, "myfile.txt");
            FileWriter gpxwriter = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(gpxwriter);
            out.write("Hello world");
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

From the above code my application always saving myfile.txt file on internal sdcard but not external sdcard-ext.And my application is support all devices with same code.

How can i save myfile.txt on sdcard-ext(external) not on sdcard(internal) in my device?

please any body help me....

Comment: I had a similiar problem this week and it turned out I had to manually define the external location by appending "/external_sd" to the getExternalStorage() for the galaxy tab, I can't find the article where I read that though sorry!

Comment: if not possible please vote on it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motorola has an API for this. Look here: http://developer.motorola.com/docs/motorola-external-storage-api/ But that's not a good generic solution. You probably need to scan the filesystem for a more generic solution that will work on all devices.

Comment: I am looking support my app to all android devices

Comment: but the motorola sdk for only motorola devices

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answer [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location), [especially the one from Baron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29107397/2823516)