# What is the correct path for the root sdcard directory

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have this code,

```
  public static boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if( path.exists() ) {
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                    deleteDirectory(files[i]);
                }
                else {
                    files[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
        return(path.delete());
    }
```

I want to call this method and delete SDcards' contents, what path should i use ?

Comment: you want to delete all the files or just your own files in sdcard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find an external SD card location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)

Comment: @H2CO3 : it doesn't except that as type File, i must add something as type File

Answer (score 3):

use

[`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) to get the external storage directory

Check the documentation before you use it.