# Get the right external storage from Android devices

Tags: android

I tried to figure out the the right external storage (additional sdcard with more space ) location of an Android device.
I know from different user, that the location is not always the same. 
The method `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory` returns me always `mnt/sdcard`.

I have the following variants are reported from users:

1. mnt/sdcard/tflash
2. mnt/sdcard/external_sd
3. mnt/sdcard

How can I determine the real location of an external sd-card?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find an external SD card location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState() returns path to internal SD mount point like "/mnt/sdcard"
```

No, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` refers to whatever the device manufacturer considered to be "external storage". On some devices, this is removable media, like an SD card. On some devices, this is a portion of on-device flash. Here, "external storage" means "the stuff accessible via USB Mass Storage mode when mounted on a host machine", at least for Android 2.x and above.

```
But the question is about external SD. How to get a path like "/mnt/sdcard/external_sd" (it may differ from device to device)?
```

Android has no concept of "external SD", aside from external storage, as described above.

If a device manufacturer has elected to have external storage be on-board flash and also has an SD card, you will need to contact that manufacturer to determine whether or not you can use the SD card (not guaranteed) and what the rules are for using it, such as what path to use for it.

Comment: not much, actualy. Both my devices have 2 ext storages each, getExternalStorageDirectory() gives me only one of them (on one device it is sdcard, on another - it is onboard ext storage). This kinda stupid, because I can also plug flash memory via microUSB into it, even card reader. So it seems that the only way is enumerate mounted storage devices by a hand

Comment: Great answer. Too bad it belongs to someone else, huh? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5695129/2608235

Answer (score 0):

> How can I determine the real location of an external sd-card?

=> Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() gives you the exact location of your external storage device. Path may be different because it depends on the consideration of manufacturer.

For example: I found **/sdcard** on some HTC devices and **/mnt/sdcard** on some samsung devices.

So `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is the correct way.