# Is "mnt/sdcard" always the external storage in Android?

Tags: android, memory, external, sd-card

In all the devices I have had the sd card has always been mounted on the path `/mnt/sdcard` (this value is also returned by the function `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath())`

Can I consider it as a constant or are there cases in which it is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On samsung galaxy s2 /sdcard is phone external memory. micro sd is under /sdcard/external_sd

Comment: But, without a rooted phone, can you write in both memories? Or you have access just to one of them?

Comment: access via file manager is to both memories. And without rooted phone. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)

Comment: Ok. I asked it because developers guide says "In devices with multiple external storage directories (such as both secure app storage and mountable shared storage), this directory represents the "primary" external storage that the user will interact with."

Than another related question: is there a function for obtaining the path of an additional memory (if present)?

Comment: Read here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Answer (score 6):

**`No`**. You can't consider as Constant its change sometime  **`/sdcard`** only.So use **`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`** for path.

Answer (score 1):

No , the external storage can be a **removable storage media (such as an SD card)** or an **internal (non-removable)** storage.