# How to get the external SDCard?

Tags: android, external, sd-card

I want to get the external SDCard path. I use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and get the internal sdcard `/mnt/sdcard/`. My external sdcard is`/storage/extSdCard`.

How to get it programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5694933/1531054

Comment: http://sapienmobile.com/?p=204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File storageDir = new File("/mnt/");
if(storageDir.isDirectory()){
String[] dirlst = storageDir.list();
//TODO some type of selecton method
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

For eg: File f= new File("/mnt/extSdCard/");

new File("/mnt/external_sd/")

or

new File("/mnt/extSdCard/")

in replace of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Hope it might help you.