# getExternalStorageDirectory not working

Tags: java, android, sd-card

I am trying to save a file to my SDcard on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus running 4.2.2. From my app I am using

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

But it returns

```
/storage/emulated/0/
```

Which is not where my SDcard information is located to. Is there any working method I can use to get the correct path to my SDcard?

Comment: can you show more code so that we can get what you tried ?

Comment: Actually it might be. The os probably loads the sd card there, and creates a virtual representation as a drive in the root

Comment: Paths changed since 4.2 due to multiuser feature

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti And what is the solution. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Here is full answer on your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734564/where-is-my-sdcard-location-on-4-4-2

Comment: I am using Samsung tab 8 and i get the same issue. What i'm going to do is check if the path is valid and or replace /emulated/0 with emulated/legacy

Answer (score 15):

Actually, that is the correct location.

From android 4,2 onwards, Google introduced multiple user accounts. Every user has his/her own external storage, which has the user ID in the path to maintain uniqueness.

The primary (default) user's ID is 0. So you get `/storage/emulated/0/` as the path to the external storage.

Comment: theres only legacy in that folder, not a 0 folder. also there no problem with using this method on my other apps, just this one.

Comment: @LukePring It's a symlink. It's not an actual folder.

Comment: You mean there SHOULD be a symlink in there.  /storage/emulated/0: No such file or directory

Comment: Android is using a fuse filesystem while running the app. The 0 directory does not exist on disk (via adb shell), but it does exist from within your app.

Comment: there is a legacy folder which is that "0"

Answer (score 10):

I just learned this is the Jelly Bean's way of dealing with the lack of `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. I haven't seen such a behavior with older versions of Android.

Just add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This doesn't fix it per se.  I have that set in my Manifest and it still comes back as **/storage/emulated/0**.  When I use the shell for the device **/storage/emulated/0** doesn't exist.  Instead of **0**, **legacy** is there.

Comment: @MichaelNguyen You can not see the **/storage/emulated/0** directory from adb shell (not even as root). It only exists in the processes launched by the user. You should see it from a terminal emulator on the device, and access it from any app.

Answer (score 5):

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` refers to whatever the device manufacturer considered to be "external storage". I can be something else than the SD-card.

You may get more informations here: [Find an external SD card location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of using genymotion emulator,
the path is true and in Eclipse it locates at

```
File Explorer - > mnt - > shell - > emulated -> 0
```

hope  it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sure? Where do you think your sdcard is mounted? Try doing `ls -l` on that directory – it's probably a symlink to `/storage/emulated/0/`.

Comment: I'm using ls -l at the moment for a different app, the symlink shows up to the app but not to my terminal which is the weirdest thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had somehow lost my symlink at /storage/emulated/0, causing a similar failure.  What I did was use the camera app to take a picture.  I observed that the pictures details said it was within /storage/emulated/0, though that directory did not exist from the file explorer.  Then I rebooted the phone.  After reboot the link existed.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`.

From [Android 4.2 documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html)

Comment: Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) returns a path of /storage/emulated/0/Pictures
Which still is invalid on my N7

Comment: And I understand that it should be available for the application (not adb) during runtime, but cannot find any files in that directory when I clearly have multiple files. (ls /mnt/shell/emulated/0/Pictures/*jpg)