# How to get notified of each new image being visible to the gallery app?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-camera, media, android-mediascanner

### Background

When the user downloads a new image or captures one using the camera, the gallery app will get updated to show the new images.

I need to be notified of each new image as soon as it was created, no matter how it was created (camera, browser,...) , just as the gallery app shows.

### The problem

As it turns out there is a mediaScanner Android component that is responsible for scanning all types of media files, and when it finishes, it's supposed to send an intent "[**MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED)" (as shown on [**this example**](http://sudarnimalan.blogspot.co.il/2012/05/android-how-to-check-if-media-scanner.html)) .

So I've added the next code , hoping it will show a toast each time the user takes a photo from the camera app:

manifest:

```
    ...
    <receiver android:name="com.example.newgalleryimagereceivertest.MediaScannerBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    ...
```

java file:

```
package com.example.newgalleryimagereceivertest;
...
public class MediaScannerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        android.util.Log.d("AppLog", "gallery has new images");
    }
```

For some reason , this code doesn't work ...

### The question

What's wrong with the code?

Will the broadcastReceiver ever be called after taking a photo?

What is the correct way to do it?

Do I really need to use a contentObserver and monitor its changes (using something like [**this**](http://www.jessechen.net/blog/tag/stack-overflow/)), and keep the app running just for this? I really hope not...

Comment: I know Toast have some limitations for it to work. UI thread and activity context. So, before saying the code doesn't work. Could you make a log instead and double check `Log.d("toast", "gallery have new images");`

Comment: yes, using logs also shown it doesn't work. will now update the code here too. also found a weird thing on the manifest here that i've fixed.

Comment: It's just a guess, perhaps [`"android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE) or `"com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE"` is called instead

Comment: @a.ch. this will be called only by the native camera app and only from a certain API . I wish to be notified of any image that the gallery can show, and not being restricted by a specific app. third party cameras don't use this intent when a new picture is taken.

Comment: Hello,have you got the solution?. I was stuck at same point.

Comment: @AmolSawant96Kuli I found 2 possible solutions, each has its own disadvantages: contentObserver, which will require constant listening, and a polling mechanism, which will check for new content once every X minutes. all other solutions I've found will affect performance and/or memory usage too much to be used.

Comment: Thank you for replying dear, still i am finding the solution. If you will get any solution then let me know.

Comment: @AmolSawant96Kuli i've stopped searching, but if i find about it, i will post an answer here.

Comment: @AmolSawant96Kuli did you found any solution for the same ? I am stuck in similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/45813687/4732786

Comment: @AdarshSharma I stopped handling this issue. Maybe one of the below answers can help you.

Answer (score 5):

[**ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED) is used for adding new *directories* to the gallery:

> Broadcast Action: The media scanner has finished scanning a directory.
>   The path to the scanned directory is contained in the Intent.mData
>   field.
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED"

You should use [**ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE), which is used to add new *files* - not just directories:

> Broadcast Action: Request the media scanner to scan a file and add it
>   to the media database. The path to the file is contained in the
>   Intent.mData field.
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE"

You can test this `Intent` using the code discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18086913/763080).

Additionally, [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152838/why-isnt-my-app-on-the-list-of-apps-to-open-txt-file) have reportedly needed to include *mime type* and file extensions, such as:

```
<data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.png" />
```

Comment: sadly, i still get nothing. did it work for you? did you run your app, and when you take a picture using the camera, did you get an intent?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I added more to the answer regarding mime types and file extensions. Does this do the trick?

Comment: still nothing. i've also tried android:pathPattern=".*\\.jpg" and android:pathPattern=".*\\.jpeg" . i wonder if it's a regular expression or just wildcards.

Comment: I don't think these two options are as analogous as stated in the answer. As stated in the docs, _SCAN_FILE is to *request* a scan, while _SCANNER_FINISHED is to notify that the media scanner *has* finished. The _SCANNER_FINISHED broadcast notifies you that there is new data, but then you'd need to query the media store to find the new data, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into adding these to your filter as well:

```
com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE
com.android.camera.NEW_VIDEO
android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE
android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO
```

The android.hardware.x actions are the "official" current broadcasts, but the com.android.x ones are sent by Samsung devices and older versions of Android.

Comment: The question is too old so I don't need it anymore. However, this is interesting. What happens with devices of other OEMs ? Do they work well?

Comment: @androiddeveloper so how you solve your problem? can you tell us about your method?

Comment: @HendraWijayaDjiono I didn't solve it, because I don't have it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can acheive this using the [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html)  .

as mentioned in the documentation :

**Monitors files  to fire an event after files are accessed or changed by by any process on the device .
Each FileObserver instance monitors a single file or directory. If a directory is monitored, events will be triggered for all files and subdirectories inside the monitored directory.**

but you have to keep in mind  :

**If a FileObserver is garbage collected, it will stop sending events. To ensure you keep receiving events, you must keep a reference to the FileObserver instance from some other live object.**

Please give me some feedback .
Hope That helps .

Comment: how would I know to which files to listen to? only files that are stored for the mediaStore should be monitored ... did you try it out? how do you monitor a specific process, and which one should it be for the mediaStore? how would you make the fileObserver observe all files from all directories, instead of a single one (it doesn't seem to be recursive) ? you would have to create an instance for every folder on the device, and also for each new one...

Comment: for example : you can listen to your pictures directory like the following :
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(             Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); 

and so on for your directories . 
and no i havent tried it .
you dont want to monitor which process created the file , you will monitor any file created by any process in the device .

Comment: but i don't want to monitor every single file created, as some won't get into the mediaStore (and maybe most of them). i also don't want to monitor just this single folder that you've written, since users can install apps that put image files (like third party cameras) on other folder , that still make the gallery app aware of those files...

Comment: cant you monitor the SD card for instance ? i dont know if what i am saying is correct or not .

Comment: i've read about it now. it doesn't seem to be able to work recursively - you would have to create a lot of FileObservers yourself - one for each directory , and even for new ones... for each file you would have to check if it got into the mediaStore... i think it can be an overkill...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46410/discussion-between-amrola-and-android-developer)

Comment: sorry i don't have time to chat. this question is written while i work at the office...

Comment: I think the problem with this approach is that you'd need to have your app running at all times. One of the benefits of a broadcast is that it would wake up your app if necessary.

Comment: in case you need monitor the sub directories, you can use this RecursiveFileObserver class https://collimator.googlecode.com/svn-history/r22/trunk/src/com/toraleap/collimator/util/RecursiveFileObserver.java

Comment: @parkerfath indeed, but can live in the background with service too. I can achieve it with create a background service to store reference to the FileObserver, so the FileObserver will not garbage collected. And on the background service, i use START_STICKY flag onStartCommand, so it will be recreated if killed by the android system, like when device on low memory