# images not showing in gallery app after inserting to sd card

Tags: android, gallery

I saved multiple images to the sdcard and it doesn't appear in the Gallery application until i restart my device..
After restarting my device images are visible..
I have tried many links but not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get notified of each new image being visible to the gallery app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311207/how-to-get-notified-of-each-new-image-being-visible-to-the-gallery-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also faced same problem..Have you tried this ??

```
File imageFile = ...
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { imageFile.getPath() }, new String[] { "image/jpeg" }, null);
```