# How to set custom music on Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to make a music player that can play all music on my memory card.
I use this code for play a music, but i can't play music from memory card, only in raw folder.

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.id.raw.audio.mp3)
```

what I should do, so i can play music from SD card ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208078/playing-music-from-sd-card-works-on-emulator-but-not-on-phone.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do something like this

```
    Uri song = Uri.parse(location-of-song); //location-of-song is where the music is on the sd card
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), song);
    mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: i want get the location from user input

Comment: you'll want to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983905/android-programming-making-a-uri-to-get-audio-location

Answer (score 0):

Use the version of create that takes a URI, and provide a URI to the local file you want to play.

Comment: like this ? file:///sdcard/music.mp3