# Phonegap / Cordova - List External Storage files (SD card)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to build a mini File Explorer, I've got it working; but can only list the internal storage (local) - I can't seem to access the external SD Card.

Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
function getFiles(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onRequestFileSystem, function (evt){alert("ERRR... 1");});
}

function onRequestFileSystem(fileSystem) {
    var directoryReader = fileSystem.root.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries(onReadEntries, function (evt){alert("ERRR... 2");});
}

function onReadEntries(entries) {
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        console.log(entries[i].name+ "  " + i);
    }
}
```

**1) How would I list the contents of my SD Card.**

**2) The S3 I'm using lists the SD card as extSdCard (img attached) - but I know other devices don't use this naming convention; the Xperia's SD card is /storage/sdcard1 - is there a consistent way of referencing external storage?**

[image: S3 SD Cards]

Answer (score 2):

You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15612964/3033467), it helped me a lot building an android file explorer.

It's a java code you should use with a javascriptInterface : Create a class implementing this code, and add this interface like this in the onCreate of your MainActivity :

`myClass = new MyClass (this, appView, this);
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(myClass , "myClass ");`

Then, you'll be able to call it from javascript this way :

```
window.myClass .getAllStorageLocations();
```

Comment: Do you have an idea on why I can't see appView.addJavascriptInterface even though importing `android.webkit.JavascriptInterface` ?

Answer (score 1):

1) I figured out a solution to scan sdcard and gain access to the files by providing a directory like *file://storage/sdcard1/* ( path to my SDcard  ).
2) I don't have an answer. 
I've submit an API and a sample project
https://github.com/xjxxjx1017/cordova-phonegap-android-sdcard-full-external-storage-access-library
Hope it could be helpful.

**Example of using the API**

```
new ExternalStorageSdcardAccess( fileHandler ).scanPath( "file:///storage/sdcard1/music" );
function fileHandler( fileEntry ) {
    console.log( fileEntry.name + " | " + fileEntry.toURL() );
}
```

**The API source code**

```
var ExternalStorageSdcardAccess = function ( _fileHandler, _errorHandler ) {

    var errorHandler = _errorHandler || _defultErrorHandler;
    var fileHandler = _fileHandler || _defultFileHandler;
    var root = "file:///";

    return {
        scanRoot:scanRoot,
        scanPath:scanPath
    };

    function scanPath( path ) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, _gotFiles, errorHandler );
    }

    function scanRoot() {
        scanPath( root );
    }

function _gotFiles(entry) {
    // ? Check whether the entry is a file or a directory
    if (entry.isFile) {
        // * Handle file
        fileHandler( entry );
    }
    else {
        // * Scan directory and add media
        var dirReader = entry.createReader();
        dirReader.readEntries( function(entryList) {
            entryList.forEach( function ( entr ) {
                _gotFiles( entr );
            } );
        }, errorHandler );
    }
}

    function _defultFileHandler(fileEntry){
        console.log( "FileEntry: " + fileEntry.name + " | " + fileEntry.fullPath );
    }
    function _defultErrorHandler(error){
        console.log( 'File System Error: ' + error.code );
    }
};
```

**Configurations**

- **config.xml**
  **delete preference:** preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems"
- make sure testing environment can **access** it's own external storage at the time of testing. ( e.p. if you connect it with usb, make sure it is connected as a camera; Call the APIs after recieving the "deviceready" event )

**Path example:**
file:///
file:///somefile/
file:///somefile
file:///somefile/music/aaaaa.mp3