# Android: write files to external sd card programatically

Tags: android

My app can write and delete file from the android sd card by adding the

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
```

But this does not work with the external SD card some devices support. Writing to the default SD card (**/mnt/sdcard0** in most cases) has no problem, but this does not work with the extra sd cards (**/mnt/sdcard1** ).

I have googled about this and also gone through some threads in stackoverfolw itself, but still i am not able to find a proper solution.

Is it really a bug in android? Is there any workaround for this?

I will really appreciate any clarification on this.

Comment: Dont hardcode SDCard, use getExternalStorageDirectory ()

Comment: Try checking the state of the SD card before you attempt to write to it. It may be used as a shared drive, corrupted, full, etc. A list of states can be found here [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)

Comment: if your os is KitKat then a Security is added from API-19:
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html
and 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() gives you the path. Try with this solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location/15612964#15612964

Comment: I am able to read the files for the external SD card. But the problem is I can not write or delete from this external SD card. It behaves as read only. I am able to list all the files from the external SD card. Writing files in the default SD card doesn't have any problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path of sdcard from this code:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Then specify the foldername and file name.

if you are using an emulator, double-check to make sure that you have filled in a value for the `SD Card` size.

Comment: I am able to read the files for the external SD card. But the problem is I can not write or delete from this external SD card. It behaves as read only.

Comment: Are you using Emulator for running this application?

Comment: No, I am testing on a real device.