# Where is the code for SD card storage option in CyanogenMod's camera app?

Tags: android, storage, cyanogenmod

I'm using CyanogenMod 10.2.1 on an Xperia ZR. This device has an emulated SD card and a removable SD card. The stock camera app has an option to store images in the emulated or the removable SD card (see screenshots below).

I'm writing a [camera app](https://github.com/phunehehe/fooCam) and I want to do the same thing, so I looked at the code of the camera app [in Android's source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera/+/android-4.3.1_r1/src/com/android/camera/Storage.java) and [in CyanogenMod's source](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Camera/blob/cm-10.2/src/com/android/camera/Storage.java). The first uses [`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) and the second [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()). Neither of those seem to be dynamic, so where does the setting item come from?

Here are some screenshots showing the storage option:

[image: s]
[image: s]

All in all, I want to find out whether those apps use the techniques in [Find an external SD card location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5694933/168034) to access secondary storage.