# How to get external storage mount points

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I am trying to get the mount points for all storage (local and external).

This worked great until I went to 4.3:

[Find an external SD card location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)

I know these mounts can be read only but that is ok.  I also know that the mounts can still be discovered in 4.3+ because ES File Explorer app can find the mount points.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have permissions to at least read from external storage then try this:

Kotlin:

```
fun getExternalRootFolders(): List<File> {
    return context.getExternalFilesDirs(null)
            .filter { canUseExternalPath(it) }
            .map { File(it.toString().substringBefore("/Android")) }
}

private fun canUseExternalPath(path: File?): Boolean {
    return path?.let { Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED == EnvironmentCompat.getStorageState(path) } == true
}
```