# Add path to ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am playing with video compression by using ffmpeg. I can compress the video e.g. with this line:

```
String commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit3/Dani.mp4 -strict experimental -s 320x240-r 30 -aspect 4:3 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -b 512k /sdcard/videokit3/Dani2.mp4";
```

In this line the path is hardcoded, so I did

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "videokit3/Dani.mp4";
```

which results `in /mnt/sdcard/videokit3/Dani.mp4`

This seems to be different from /sdcard/videokit3/Dani.mp4 so this line runs to error (I see the difference, I just don't get it):

```
String commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i " + path + " -strict experimental -s 320x240 -r 30 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -b 512k /sdcard/videokit3/Dani4.mp4";
```

Can you help?

Comment: Noone? Why is this nowehere documented?

Comment: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5695129/2777098

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get around would be replace the string and trim "/mnt" out before inserting into the statement. The reason why the external SDcard absolute path returns as "mounted" drive is available here on SO: [stackoverflow.com/a/5695129/2777098](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5695129/2777098)

Comment: I thought about that but what's the guarantee it will work on all devices?

Comment: It may not depending on the manufacturer and their implementation of "external storage". When I use ffmpeg, I temporarily make a copy of the video to a folder my program created and work from there. Hope this helps.