# How to display external storage image in imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I want to display external storage image like:

"storage/sdcard0/image.jpg"

in my android  application.

can any one guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/5695129/571353

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your image is in the root folder of sdcard then  access it through

```
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString + File.separator + "yourimage.jpg");     
 webImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 3):

this is the right way to do this:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "image.jpg");     
myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

but is necessary add the permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

or require this permission manually for OS 6.0+ :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

 int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {      
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this function:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"image.png");
```

Set this bitmap to imageview:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```