# android get image from gallery and save another activity

Tags: java, android

I am making an app 'food maker' but the problem  first is  how to pick an image from the gallery second save this image into external storage like SQLite and shared preferences 3rd this store image and some title  how I retrieve this image and title an another activity to open this and see this that set .....

Comment: See if this link helps.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database

Answer (score -1):

Welcome, Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

You are asking multiple questions and i am not sure where your problem is...

i'll try to tackle the problems 1 by 1.

1. picking an image from gallery can be done by following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309217/9233991)
2. saving a file to external storage can be done by following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7887114/9233991)
3. you can display/load an image from external storage by following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24509181/9233991)

Good luck