# Android java how to get memory card path

Tags: java, android

i want to know how can we get memory card path.
am using

File extMemDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

but it return path of mounted storage on device not removable SD card on my samsung device

please help i need path of removable SD card

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns the path of external storage directory. That's fine

Comment: thats not fine .... it return  /mnt/sdcard       , there will be any method to get path of sdcard

Comment: read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ever wil return the manufacturer's external storage, sometimes is SdCard, some others is Internal Storage...

Here you can get the explanation of this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location and solutions

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable way to determine the path to a micro SD card for all devices. On some you can use getExternalStorageDirectory().

If the device runs kitkat you might try to use getExternalFileDirs() which can return several paths.

Make an option in your app so the user can indicate the right path and save the choice in shared preferences.