# java.io.FileNotFoundException when trying to save a map's screenshot

Tags: java, android

i' m getting this exception when i try to save the screenShot into my download folder ***inside my  phone's memory not the SdCard***.
I checked the path and it's correct and i have also this permission defined into my xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

screenShot's function:

```
public void captureMapScreen() {
        SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                bitmap = snapshot;
                try {
                    // storage path (where image will be stored) + name of image
                    // you can customize as per
                    // your Requirement
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/Download/" + "MyMapScreen" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                            + ".png");
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        map.snapshot(callback);
    }
```

my logcat:

```
09-15 11:02:09.323: W/System.err(26419): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/Download/MyMapScreen1410771729328.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-15 11:02:09.323: W/System.err(26419):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
09-15 11:02:09.323: W/System.err(26419):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
09-15 11:02:09.323: W/System.err(26419):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
09-15 11:02:09.323: W/System.err(26419):    at com.logic.maps.activity.MapsActivity$1.onSnapshotReady(MapsActivity.java:317)
09-15 11:02:09.323: W/System.err(26419):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$5.g(Unknown Source)
09-15 11:02:09.323: W/System.err(26419):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.s$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
09-15 11:02:09.323: W/System.err(26419):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
09-15 11:02:09.323: W/System.err(26419):    at gtu.a(SourceFile:117)
09-15 11:02:09.331: W/System.err(26419):    at ovg.a(Unknown Source)
09-15 11:02:09.331: W/System.err(26419):    at ovi.run(Unknown Source)
09-15 11:02:09.331: W/System.err(26419):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-15 11:02:09.331: W/System.err(26419):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-15 11:02:09.331: W/System.err(26419):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-15 11:02:09.331: W/System.err(26419):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
09-15 11:02:09.331: W/System.err(26419):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 11:02:09.331: W/System.err(26419):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-15 11:02:09.331: W/System.err(26419):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
09-15 11:02:09.331: W/System.err(26419):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
09-15 11:02:09.331: W/System.err(26419):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-15 11:02:09.331: W/System.err(26419): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-15 11:02:09.338: W/System.err(26419):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
09-15 11:02:09.338: W/System.err(26419):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
09-15 11:02:09.338: W/System.err(26419):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
09-15 11:02:09.338: W/System.err(26419):    ... 18 more
```

**UPDATE:**

my archive tree: (no sdCard inside my phone, only phone memory)

```
storage
 - sdcard0
   - download
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find an external SD card location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the subdirectory `Download` exists there.

Seeing the update, it seems you want to store to an emulated SD card. Try `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and also note that file names are case sensitive.

Comment: well the directory Download exists inside my phone.It's weird, is there any other command to enter inside phone's archive?

Comment: Well, if the directory is `/storage/sdcard0/download` it's clear that storing to `/data/Download` fails.

Comment: i read that `getData` is used to store inside phone's memory or not?

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.getDataDirectory()` does not point to the sdcard, however it points to somewhere in `/data`.

You need to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead, as it points to what the manufacturor has defined as the path for the external storage, i.e. sdcard.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

> File storageDir = Environment
>                       .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
>
> file = new File(storageDir, "MyMapScreen" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");
>     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);