# available space in sd card and internal memory

Tags: android, sd-card

i want to get available space in SD card and the internal memory

i used following code to get available space in internal memory

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
        double sdAvailSize = (double) stat.getAvailableBlocks()
                * (double) stat.getBlockSize();
        // One binary gigabyte equals 1,073,741,824 bytes.
        double gigaAvailable = sdAvailSize / 1073741824;
```

But is thr anyway that i can get available space in SD card , i know for sure that i cannot use SD card on Kit-kat , but if i am using jelly beans , is thr anyway that i can access to SD card available space

Device 4.1.2

Comment: use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know the path to external SD card on pre-KitKat devices, the API [getExternalFilesDirs()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs%28java.lang.String%29) is available only in KitKat.
You can use various hacks to guess the SD card path, for example reading /proc/mounts, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9315813/624766)