# Unable to write to external SD Card in Android

Tags: android, io, android-sdcard

I am trying to write files in the external SD card folder. Even after having set the required permission in the manifest file, I am unable to write on the external SD card.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Code:

```
String path = "/mnt/extsd/nit.txt";

    File myFile = new File(path);

    if (!myFile.exists()) {
       try {
           myFile.createNewFile();
       } catch(Exception e)
       {
           txtText.setText("Failed-" + e.getMessage());
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

try {
            FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter oswriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fostream);
            BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(oswriter);
            bwriter.write("Hi welcome ");
            bwriter.newLine();
            bwriter.close();
            oswriter.close();
            fostream.close();
            txtText.setText("success");
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            txtText.setText("Failed-" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

On the other hand when I use ES File Explorer and try to create a file, it creates it without any issues.

Comment: Try this way:   `File dir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"+java.io.File.separator+"nit.txt");` do not hard code PATH

Comment: On which API you are testing?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Error message is: open failed: EACCES (Permission Denied)
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 20

Comment: I have the same problem.  Have you ever solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the absolute path `String path = "/mnt/extsd/nit.txt";` because you never know about android device being used by users. Rather you can get the external storage directory path by using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()`.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() doesn't give path of external SD card. It gives the path of internal storage which is mapped as external storage by the tab manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get the root path to the SD card and use that to create a FileOutputStream. From there, just use the standard java.io routines.

```
File log = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "your_file_name.txt");
    try {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(log.getAbsolutePath(), false));
        out.write("any data");

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

And don't forget to close the streams.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() doesn't give path of external SD card. It gives the path of internal storage which is mapped as external storage by the tab manufacturer.

Comment: So you don't want to write the file if mobile doesn't have an mounted sdcard support

Answer (score 0):

First check sd-card is available or not.

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
{
File folder = folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "FolderName");
if(!folder.exists())
{
    folder.mkdir();//making folder
}
File file = new File(folder,"Filename");//making file
}
```

Please try this code, it work in my application.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() doesn't give path of external SD card. It gives the path of internal storage which is mapped as external storage by the tab manufacturer.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() is giving me /mnt/sdcard, which is the path of internal storage.

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)