# App runs fine on emulator, but crashes on real device

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I have tried doing an app which parses xml files. In the emulator it works fine, but when I run it in real device, android phone and android tablet, it crashes ...

This is the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public List<UnitModel> model = null;
    private String filename = "ModelInfo.txt";
    UnitModelParser parser = new UnitModelParser();

    public List<Gps> coordinate = new ArrayList<Gps>();
    private String fName;
    GpsXmlParser gpsParser = new GpsXmlParser();
    ArrayList<Gps> coorList = gpsParser.getItemsList();

    String TAG = "Test";
    private static final String FOLDER_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Gps/";
    File dir = new File (FOLDER_PATH);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new LoadModelTask().execute();
        Button btnModel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnModel);
        btnModel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // write on SD card file data in the text box
                    if (isWritable()) {
                        ArrayList<UnitModel> modelList = parser.getItemsList();
                        UnitModel modd = modelList.get(0);

                          StringBuilder locationStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                          locationStrBuilder.append(modd);
                          String locationStrModel = locationStrBuilder.toString();
                          fName = locationStrModel + ".txt";
                    try {
                        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                        File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/GpsOutput");
                        directory.mkdirs();
                        File myFile = new File(directory, filename);

                   myFile.createNewFile();
                   FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);
                   OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                   myOutWriter.append(locationStrModel + "\n");
                   myOutWriter.close();
                   fOut.close();
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Successfully acquired the unit information.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   System.out.println("Model ID : " + locationStrModel);
                  } 
                  catch (Exception e) {
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } 
                    }
                  else 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"SD Card Not Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                });

        new LoadGpsTask().execute();
        Button btnGps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGps);
        btnGps.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        StringBuilder locationStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        int s = 0;
                        for (Gps c : coordinate)
                        {
                            locationStrBuilder.append(c.toString());
                            System.out.println(++s + c.toString());
                        }

                        if (isWritable()) {
                        try {
                            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                            File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/GpsOutput");
                            directory.mkdirs();
                            File myFile = new File(directory, fName);

                       myFile.createNewFile();
                       FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile, false);
                       OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                       myOutWriter.append(locationStrBuilder);
                       myOutWriter.close();
                       fOut.close();
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Successfully downloaded gps coordinate.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      } 
                      catch (Exception e) {
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      } } 
                      else 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"SD Card Not Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }); 
                }// onCreate

        private class LoadModelTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<UnitModel>> {              
                @Override
                protected List<UnitModel> doInBackground(String... args) {              
                    // CALL XMLPULLPARSER & RETURN A LIST           
                    model = parser.parse(getBaseContext());
                    return model;   
                }
        }

        //filenamefilter method
        public FilenameFilter xmlFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.endsWith(".xml") || name.endsWith(".XML");
            }
        };

        private class LoadGpsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Gps>> {
            @Override
            protected List<Gps> doInBackground(String... args) {
                // CALL XMLPULLPARSER & RETURN A LIST           
                String files[] = dir.list(xmlFilter);
                for (String filename : files) {
                       String path = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename;
                       Log.i(TAG, path);
                       System.out.println("PARSING : " + path);
                       coordinate.addAll(gpsParser.parse(path));
                       Log.i(TAG,"message");
                       Log.i(TAG,coordinate.size() + "");
                }
                Log.i(TAG,coordinate.size() + "");
                return coordinate;
            }
        }

        public boolean isWritable() {
            String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(status)) 
            {
              return true;
            }
                  return false;
         } //isWritable
}
```

And this is the output of logcat:

```
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942):     at asp.xmlreader.MainActivity$LoadGpsTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:152)
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942):     at asp.xmlreader.MainActivity$LoadGpsTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-15 14:03:35.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2942):     ... 4 more
05-15 14:03:35.041: V/InputMethodManager(2942): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#1810100
05-15 14:03:35.042: V/InputMethodManager(2942): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41377878 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-768,976} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@413a1d28 controlFlags=#104
05-15 14:03:35.044: V/InputMethodManager(2942): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@413a2678 com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME #16}
05-15 14:03:36.076: D/OpenGLRenderer(2942): Flushing caches (mode 0)
05-15 14:03:36.174: D/OpenGLRenderer(2942): Flushing caches (mode 0)
05-15 14:03:36.178: D/OpenGLRenderer(2942): Flushing caches (mode 1)
05-15 14:03:36.183: D/OpenGLRenderer(2942): Flushing caches (mode 0)
05-15 14:03:38.085: I/Process(2942): Sending signal. PID: 2942 SIG: 9
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens? Thank you for not bashing as I am new to this.

Comment: Might be your FOLDER_PATH related problem.

Comment: System.out.println("PARSING : " + path); Whats the output  of this? Most likely this is null

Comment: Which line in your code is line 152 ?

Comment: ohh wait, thanks, ill be checking on that. thank you

Comment: have You set permission for write external storage?

Comment: thank you thank you guys. ill be commenting output if found another prob

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, I do have permission set on the manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe u need to create the folder on new device

private static final String FOLDER_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Gps/";

File dir = new File (FOLDER_PATH);

```
    private class LoadGpsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Gps>>                                             {
        @Override
        protected List<Gps> doInBackground(String... args) {
            //create folder if not exist
            boolean success = true;
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                success = dir.mkdir();
            }
            if (!success) {
                // Do something else on failure 
            }
            // CALL XMLPULLPARSER & RETURN A LIST           
            String files[] = dir.list(xmlFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems on different devices and Android versions with finding real path to External Storage(if it is available) looks like you faced one of them, please look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location), hope it would help you to find workaround for your task.