# SD card path not pointing

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard, usb-otg

I have application which require synchronize operation with SD card,USB DRIVE,Dropbox. I successfully implemented Dropbox sync but got stuck while doing it with SD Card and USB.When i try to retrieve external storage path it always return internal memory path.How should i point to SD Card path if SD card present.

[image]

Comment: Any Suggestion or link help needed

Comment: What brand phone/tablet are you trying to work with?

Comment: The reason I ask is because some brands, like specifically Samsung, do not allow write access to third-party apps. That's why if you're dealing with Samsung devices, `getExternalStorageDirectory()` simply redirects to internal storage.

Comment: Thanks,But i want to code independent of phone manufacturer means it should general so that it would work on all phones

Comment: Right, but what I'm saying is, you can't. If you want to include all phones, you HAVE to code something up special for some brands like specifically Samsung. It's just like what people used to (maybe still do) for AJAX calls in web browsers. For AJAX, depending on the browser, you had to handle the initialization differently.
Basically, if Samsung, or some other company, maps the external storage directory to something internal, there's nothing you can do about it that without writing special code for that case. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5694933/1316483 has more info too.