# android how to get external memory card path? i want to save database backup in external storage

Tags: android, path, save, storage

I make a search on google and other.

I can not find answer about external storage/memory card path.

so please help.

Comment: I try Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(), its also give internal storage path

Comment: kindly refer this link [SD card location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to determine the path to a micro SD card. To removable storage.

getExternalStorageDirectory() will give a path to external storage and hence is unusable.

You better let the user pick the right path.

On modern systems you can try getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: What do you mean exactly?