# Access image in local storage

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi am trying to access image in assets/images/flower.png Am using `react-native-fs` but I tried different path but no luck. has anyone did this before and succeeded ?

```
var RNFS = require("react-native-fs");
this.base64RouteImage = await RNFS.readFile(
  "../../../assets/images/flower.png",
  "base64"
).then();
console.log("64 is " + base64data);
```

I tried below different path  as below

```
/images/flower.png
app/assets/images/flower.png
/app/assets/images/flower.png
file://app/assets/images/flower.png
./assets/images/flower.png
import Flower from "../../../assets/images/flower.png";
../../../assets/images/flower.png
```

EDIT 1

I have added permission read/write internal/external permission in android

EDIT 2

I tried

`RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/assets/images/flower.png"` 
but it says

`error: ENOENT: /data/user/0/com.tipll/files/assets/images/flower.png (No such file or directory)`

I need to access the images in react-native assets folder `app/assets/images/flower.png`

[image]

Still no luck

EDIT 3

my path reference from my current screen is like `../../../assets/images/flower.png`

EDIT 4

[image]

EDIT 5

Am trying to access image from `app/views/routes/view/Flower.js` this Flower.js screen.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you clear out that what paltform you are testing it on! becuase you tagged both React Techs but no platform!

Comment: react-native am on

Comment: so you want to show the flower image in an Image Component ? in android and iOS app ?

Comment: you shouldn't need `.then()` if you are using `await`

Comment: @Rizwanatta I need to local image to convert it to base64 string to load.  I need it on both iOS and Android

Comment: has your kind self been able to locate this my friend: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker

Comment: if you are aiming to upload an image and you want it work on both platforms securely and better this is the way to go!

Comment: @DanielLizik oh okay thanks.

Comment: @Rizwanatta its a picker right ? in my app I can't let user have a selection picker.  I need get only that particular image without any popups/dialogs to pick for  user. There is no upload. But I need base64 of my image  for social media share

Comment: use `const rootPath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath; //= (os == "android") ? 
 RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath :RNFS.MainBundlePath`

Comment: Pls check my edited question

Comment: please provide structure of your project

Answer (score 0):

To Access data from **internal memory**: Filepath `"/storage/emulated/0/"`.

To Access data from **external memory(SD-CARD)**: Filepath `"/storage/0000-0000/"`.

Few questions arise here,

1) How is the SD-CARD name "0000-0000"?

Well, 0000-0000 is [Volume Serial Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_serial_number), it changes every time an SD-CARD is formatted. If you want to regulate it i.e you want to add your own Serial Number, check out this post [Change Serial Number](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/189104/sd-card-gets-different-name-at-every-format).

2) How do you now what your SD-CARD Serial Number is?

You can use file managers in Playstore to know your SD-Cards Serial Number and also explore this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484564/how-can-i-retrieve-an-sd-cards-serial-number-in-android-7-0).

Comment: Is this related to android only ? Could you check my EDIT 2

Comment: I tried  "torage/emulated/0/" + "/assets/images/flower.png" I got error as Error: ENOENT: /storage/emulated/0/assets/images/flower.png (No such file or directory)

Comment: i will update my answer. i thought local storage as internal storage.

Comment: are you able to put that image in an image tag with the path that you are using.

Comment: Can you check my EDIT 3 & EDIT 4 added the structure

Answer (score 0):

If you want read from internal storage (of device) try this:

```
    file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/flower.jpg
```

I guess that you want read from a folder in your rn project... You must provide the structure of your project

So try with require('../../../assets/images/flower.png')

or try with absolute path: require('MyApp/app/assets/images/flower.png')

Comment: Can you check my EDIT 3 & EDIT 4 added the structure

Comment: you must access the image from App.js?

Comment: nope from a screen which is inside like its path is like app/views/routes/view/Flower.js

Comment: I tried require but got error `Error: ENOENT: /data/user/0/com.tipll/files16 (No such file or directory)`