# Android - API 23 Unable to get USB/SD Card Directory

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I used to get all the files in **USB/SD Card** from `"/storage/external_storage"` like so

```
File = new File("/storage/external_storage");
file.listFiles()
```

and show the files and folders in my own `Fragment` and it worked great until API 23. Where now I am unable to get the file list from the path.

I know in Android Marshmallow (23) there were permission changes *and* some [USB Connection](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-usb) behavior changes.

> If your app supports user interactions with the device over a USB port, take into consideration that the interaction must be explicitly enabled.

Does not explain how or when user can enable *interactions* explicitly.

My question is whether or not it is possible to Access USB files and Folders list.
If there is how can we achieve this?

**EDIT :** I opened Android Device Monitor and I couldn't find `external_storage` in `/storage/external_storage`.

Comment: You need to implement run time permissions or set target api ver 22.

Comment: On side note, don't hard code the path, instead use [getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

Comment: @phnmnn Thanks for you reply. I need to target api 23. However I already have the write permission. Unless there is some new USB/SD card permission required?

Comment: @Mudassir Yes but that also gives local file path for when there is no usb connected or Default external storage is set to local. I only want to show files when USB is connected.

Comment: Probably your problem comes cause of Runtime Permissions from API 23, try this: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @zapotec I considered that but which permission do I need to access USB/SD Card file and folders. If you know any such permission that please leave in comment.

Comment: Try these two ones: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>

Comment: @zapotec I tried the permissions didn't work and I checked in Android Device Monitor and there is no `external_storage` folder their. (Check my updated question).

Comment: `to access USB/SD Card file and folders`. Those are two things. You are unclear what you want to access. A removable micro SD card or a connected USB OTG drive. You also did not tell for which Android version you compile.

Comment: @greenapps don't both link to the same folder? Like `"storage/external_storage"`?

Comment: Imagine that both a micro SD card and OTG drive are available.... how could that be one folder? The folder you mention does not exist on most devices. In fact i have never seen a device that has a folder with that name. Your subject is completely wrong.

Comment: @greenapps you are right about multiple removable media attached at the same time. It does create a seperate folder. But I have successfully used "sotrage/" folder on a number of occasions, however they are not applicable on all devices. I will update question's subject accordingly.

Comment: @greenapps Is there a way to only retrieve the folders that are removable? i.e. all the usb/sd card folders?

Comment: @greenapps oops my bad, I got engaged elsewhere. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is true the doc is not very clear about that....but it seems you have to ask the system to mount the media device for you. Can you try to use 
`Environment.getExternalStorageState()` to see what it returns you?

Otherwise, you can also try to access the SD/External USB by using this class:

```
public class ExternalStorage {

public static final String SD_CARD = "sdCard";
public static final String EXTERNAL_SD_CARD = "externalSdCard";

/**
 * @return True if the external storage is available. False otherwise.
 */
public static boolean isAvailable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static String getSdCardPath() {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";
}

/**
 * @return True if the external storage is writable. False otherwise.
 */
public static boolean isWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

/**
 * @return A map of all storage locations available
 */
public static Map<String, File> getAllStorageLocations() {
    Map<String, File> map = new HashMap<String, File>(10);

    List<String> mMounts = new ArrayList<String>(10);
    List<String> mVold = new ArrayList<String>(10);
    mMounts.add("/mnt/sdcard");
    mVold.add("/mnt/sdcard");

    try {
        File mountFile = new File("/proc/mounts");
        if(mountFile.exists()){
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(mountFile);
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                if (line.startsWith("/dev/block/vold/")) {
                    String[] lineElements = line.split(" ");
                    String element = lineElements[1];

                    // don't add the default mount path
                    // it's already in the list.
                    if (!element.equals("/mnt/sdcard"))
                        mMounts.add(element);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        File voldFile = new File("/system/etc/vold.fstab");
        if(voldFile.exists()){
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(voldFile);
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                if (line.startsWith("dev_mount")) {
                    String[] lineElements = line.split(" ");
                    String element = lineElements[2];

                    if (element.contains(":"))
                        element = element.substring(0, element.indexOf(":"));
                    if (!element.equals("/mnt/sdcard"))
                        mVold.add(element);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < mMounts.size(); i++) {
        String mount = mMounts.get(i);
        if (!mVold.contains(mount))
            mMounts.remove(i--);
    }
    mVold.clear();

    List<String> mountHash = new ArrayList<String>(10);

    for(String mount : mMounts){
        File root = new File(mount);
        if (root.exists() && root.isDirectory() && root.canWrite()) {
            File[] list = root.listFiles();
            String hash = "[";
            if(list!=null){
                for(File f : list){
                    hash += f.getName().hashCode()+":"+f.length()+", ";
                }
            }
            hash += "]";
            if(!mountHash.contains(hash)){
                String key = SD_CARD + "_" + map.size();
                if (map.size() == 0) {
                    key = SD_CARD;
                } else if (map.size() == 1) {
                    key = EXTERNAL_SD_CARD;
                }
                mountHash.add(hash);
                map.put(key, root);
            }
        }
    }

    mMounts.clear();

    if(map.isEmpty()){
             map.put(SD_CARD, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    }
    return map;
}
}
```

The use is like this:

```
Map<String, File> externalLocations = ExternalStorage.getAllStorageLocations();
File sdCard = externalLocations.get(ExternalStorage.SD_CARD);
File externalSdCard = externalLocations.get(ExternalStorage.EXTERNAL_SD_CARD);
```

Source here: [Find an external SD card location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` returns "mounted", which I suppose is what I should get while the USB is connected. However in `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` I get the local shared directory path. I will give `ExternalStorage` a shot and get back to you.

Comment: I tried your code but It doesn't work. I get path to  "mnt/sdcard" which is a shared location.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `getExternalFilesDirs()`. 
If a micro SD card is inserted the second entry will point to the card.
If you then attach a USB OTG drive the third entry will point to the drive.

With Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE you can let the user choose from all drives and then use Storage Access Framework.

Comment: I will check it and get back to you.