# Android To get USB path

Tags: android, file

Can anyone tell me how to get the path of the mounted USB directory marshmallow.

Any help will be appreciated.

Many Thanks 
Asha Joney

Comment: check this if it help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41012320/android-api-23-unable-to-get-usb-sd-card-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are lucky -depending on device- you can get it as one of the items of `getExternalFilesDirs()`.

Otherwise let the user choose the pen drive with `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.