# How to use isExternalStorageRemovable(File) on older APIs?

Tags: android, android-support-library

The `isExternalStorageRemovable(File)` function on Android is available on API 21 and newer and `isExternalStorageRemovable()` only works on the primary storage which may be non-removable. Is there a compat or support function with the same functionality as `isExternalStorageRemovable(File)`?

Comment: Nope, there is not. What is your use case ?

Comment: @Dibzmania I wanted to write a function that would search the list of partitions on a device for the removable SD card and returned it. I can't use for that purpose the version without any arguments (`isExternalStorageRemovable()`) since it only checks the primary storage which is often the internal storage. I use API 11.

Comment: Well before Android 4.4, Android did not have the concept of secondary storage. So, such an API would not exist. Some good read  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location  (including the some of the links in that answer portion)